# flux store - unit tests

Tags: jasmine, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm writing unit tests for several Flux stores and encountered a small annoyance.

My stores are generally built like this:

```
storeObj = {
...
}

_secretsetterfunction = function (){}

module.exports storeObj
```

As you can see, since the setter function is outside of the store object - it's not directly accessible.

This presents a problem as the only way to test / manipulate the store data would be to go through the **Action** -> **Dispatcher** -> **event listener** (the Action can technically be cut out) which isn't something I would like to go through when unit testing a store.

The alternative is to actually put the setter methods on the store object - but this isn't something I'd really wish to do.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So The flux team just addressed this in a blog post, though they are using their own variant called Jest. Still worth a read:

http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/09/24/testing-flux-applications.html?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too, using Jasmine.

I wrote a blog post & example repo about how to get a reference to those private inner functions when you're not using Jest: http://bensmithett.com/testing-flux-stores-without-jest/

TL;DR - use [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire)

Answer (score 2):

Actions are effectively the public api of a store.  You only need to verify the effects of actions to fully test your stores.

Comment: I get that, and it does obviously work.

But it can quickly become rather complicated, especially with the waitFor() command.

Comment: Not really, it's actually very simple.  You set all of your tests to have a timeout, invoke an action, and you just wait for a change event on the store and validate the payload.  There's no simpler way to do it.  I do recommend mocha over jasmine... it has better support for this kind of thing afaik.

Comment: I don't think dependencies between React stores are such a good idea. Using principles of CQRS/EventSourcing could help testability and scale better on large teams. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/25806145/82609

Comment: @SebastienLorber That's quite interesting, but probably going to far for our needs at the moment.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand agree and that's what we are doing at the moment, still it feels like I'm doing more than a bit of extra work to test these - but I guess this is the best solution atm