# What benefits do "async actions" of redux bring?

Tags: asynchronous, middleware, redux

[Redux documentation](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) says that to do async calls—which would typically involve an action indicating the start of the async call, and a later action indicating its completion—I should use the "thunk" middleware. This allows me to write "actions creators" like this:

```
function fetchPosts(reddit) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestPosts(reddit))
    return fetch(`http://www.reddit.com/r/${reddit}.json`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(reddit, json)))
  }
}
```

(Here `requestPosts` and `receivePosts` are action creators.)

The `thunk` middleware allow me to dispatch the (function) output of `fetchPosts`, e.g.,

```
store.dispatch(fetchPosts('reactjs')).then(() =>
  ...
```

But why involve middleware at all? Why is this better than just writing my own `fetchPost` function using the global store, like this:

```
function fetchPosts(reddit) {
  store.dispatch(requestPosts(reddit));
  return fetch(`http://www.reddit.com/r/${reddit}.json`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => store.dispatch(receivePosts(reddit, json)))
  }
}
```

Obviously, I can't `dispatch` this function, but that doesn't seem terribly important. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the benefits of using thunk middleware in redux over using regular functions as async action creators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713466/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-thunk-middleware-in-redux-over-using-regular-func)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need middleware for async flow in Redux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570758/why-do-we-need-middleware-for-async-flow-in-redux)

Comment: Oh. Sorry. @user5325596 's reference is The more helpful one.