# What is the sole benefit of redux-thunk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am relatively newer to redux. I have gone through a lot of article still i am not getting a clear picture whats the real benefit of using `redux-thunk`.

All I understood is it allows you to return a function instead of object from `action-creators`? But what's the benefit? I have created few small react projects without using redux-thunk.

Let's consider the below snippets. Both behaves the same.

It would be great help if someone can explain me or point me to the correct resources to get a better understanding.

`With redux-thunk`

```js
export function fetchContacts(){
  return function(dispatch){
    axios
      .get('/contacts')
      .then( contacts => dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_CONTACTS', payload: contacts}))
  }
}
```

`Without redux-thunk`

```js
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3000",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
})
const url = '/contacts';
export function fetchContacts(){
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_CONTACTS',
    payload: client.get(url)
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713466/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-thunk-middleware-in-redux-over-using-regular-func

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use Redux Thunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47031408/why-use-redux-thunk)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of Redux itself, is to hold our application state. One of the great features of Redux is that we can change our state in a well-defined pattern and it's a pattern that we repeat over and over in our applications.

We call an **Action Creator**, this produces an **Action**. The **Action** flows into our **Middleware**, then our **Reducers** which then flows into our application **State** then into **React**. Then we sit around and wait for the user to initiate some change inside of our application that repeats the process all over again.

This process works fine with any kind of synchronous change. By synchronous I mean that we call an **Action Creator** which immediately flows into an **Action**, **Middleware** and our **Reducers**.

The vast majority of web applications we build, however, need to fetch data from asynchronous channels. In other words, its more common to call an **Action Creator** that is fetching data from an API or some asynchronous action and only when that request resolves are we actually ready to create an **Action**.

Vanilla Redux is not setup to handle this out of the box.

So, how do we handle these asynchronous **Action Creators**?

This is where Redux-Thunk comes into play. The purpose of Redux-Thunk is to give us direct control over the Dispatch method. The Dispatch method is part of the ReduxStore that contains our application state.

The Dispatch method handles:
 
**Middleware**
**Reducers**
**State**

When we normally call an **Action Creator** and it returns an **Action**, the **Action** ends up being returned into this Dispatch method. You have been using the Dispatch method behind-the-scenes in vanilla Redux.

So in practice, say you have a file in `actions/index.js`:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function fetchUsers() {
   const request = axios.get('http://somejsondata.com/users');
}
```

Redux expects us to return an action, but we do not yet have any data. I have to wait for my request to resolve before I have any data to send across to my Dispatch method.

So, lets use Redux-Thunk where all the existing rules for action creators kind of go out the window. Redux expects for us to return an **Action** which is a plain JavaScript object.

Redux-Thunk enables one other return type, which is a plain JavaScript function.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function fetchUsers() {
   const request = axios.get('http://somejsondata.com/users');

   return () => {

   };
}
```

The first argument is going to be the `dispatch` method:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function fetchUsers() {
   const request = axios.get('http://somejsondata.com/users');

   return (dispatch) => {

   };
}
```

If we pass an **Action** into `dispatch`, it's going to be sent off to all our different **reducers**.

```
export function fetchUsers() {
       const request = axios.get('http://somejsondata.com/users');

       return (dispatch) => {
         request.then(({data}) => {
           dispatch({type: 'FETCH_PROFILES', payload: data})
         });
       };
    }
```

This is saying, we are going to wait for request to resolve with some amount of data and only when it has will I dispatch an action. In this case, it is going to have `type` `FETCH_PROFILES` and `payload` of `data`.

Comment: Is there any advantage of using redux (actions) with axios to get data over getting just using axios?

Comment: Is there any advantage of using redux (actions) with axios to get data over getting just using axios?

Answer (score 4):

`redux-thunk` allows you to execute asynchronous operations.

In your first example you are sending the actual data returned by your API endpoint to your reducer. And the action will only be sent after the server has returned the data.

In your second example, you are sending a promise to your reducer which doesn't work as you would have to resolve your promise inside the reducer, which breaks the principle upon which reducers should be pure functions.

Answer (score 2):

redux-thunk allows you to delay your actions in order to make async calls before dispatching. lets say you are retrieving user settings. the common use-case is to dispatch a REQUEST_FOR_USER_SETTINGS_IN_PROGRESS action so you can show a loader in your app, then make the http request for the data and when you get a response, dispatch a SUCCESS or ERROR action to update UI. it would look something like this:

```
const requestToGetCoins = await() => {
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestToGetUserSettingsInProgress());
    try{
      const users = async httpService.getUserSettings();
      dispatch(requestToGetUserSettingsSuccess(users));
    }
    catch(e){
      dispatch(requestToGetUserSettingsError(e));
    }
};
```

};

just wanted to emphasise that there is a better way to handle async actions in redux than redux-thunk, using an adhoc middleware which handles async actions and reduces much of the boilerplate. I suggest you take a look at this:
https://medium.com/@sht_5/minimal-code-for-redux-async-actions-c47ea85f2141