# If an action needs to use some current state, who should fetch it from store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

The title may not clear enough, please consider this example:

If I have a data table, which you can select multiple rows, and click action button like `delete`.

now in my actions.js:
(`selectedRows` is an array that contains the row indexes, `getSelectedPostIds` is a selector which will fetch and convert `selectedRows` to `postIds`)

```
import { getSelectedPostIds } from 'selectors'

export const deletePosts = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  // encapsulate the parameter `postIds` in action
  const postIds = getSelectedPostIds(getState())
  dispatch({ type: 'DELETE' })
  deletePostsApi(postIds)
  // .then(...)
  // .catch(...)
}
```

is there any problem in this design? Or I should avoid using `getState` in an action and just pass `postIds` as a parameter to the action:

```
export const deletePosts = postIds => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: 'DELETE' })
  deletePostsApi(postIds)
  // .then(...)
  // .catch(...)
}
```

The only difference is that who should fetch the state (*use the selector*) from store, 1. action or 2. the component who will dispatch the action (via `mapStateToProps`).

I'm not sure about the approach 1, and the approach 2 will make my component contains a lot of props just because some actions need them (or maybe this is totally fine?).

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a matter of taste. I usually like to access `getState` directly since, as you point out, avoids passing a lot of props. And by doing that the action is easier to integrate in different components (I just need to call it instead of additionally editing the `mapStateToProps`). Also, since in the end both ways are accessing the global store, the intended redux data flow is not compromised in any way.

Comment: But I just found that Dan said that accessing state in action creator is an anti-pattern, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667249/accessing-redux-state-in-an-action-creator , but I'm still not sure about why.

Comment: Mmm... I actually use it mostly for user authentication, the case that Dan mentions as an exception. I guess then I would say try to find a compromise between lots of props and store access.

Comment: @CodinCat :  That answer from Dan frequently pops up as a concern for people.  I'm actually writing a blog post now that disagrees with Dan's statement, along with several other complaints about use of thunks.  It'll go up on my blog at http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com once I figure out exactly what I want to say.  But yeah, feel free to go ahead and access `getState` as needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use redux-thunk if you want to work with state in your action creators. :)

https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

```
function yourActionCreator() {
  // Redux-thunk will catch all action creators that return functions
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // u can use state here
    const { counter } = getState();

    if (counter % 2 === 0) {
      return;
    }
    // Dispatch your action creator as you would normally do
    dispatch(increment());
  };
}
```

Comment: I'm using thunk actually, that's why I can use `getState` in action creators