# Handling Auth State using Redux

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I have a chat-app that uses React, Redux and Firebase. I'm also using thunkmiddleware to do the async updates of the state with Firebase. 
I successfully get everything I need, except that everything depends of a previously hard-coded variable.

The question is, how can I call inside my ActionCreators the `getState()` method in order to retrieve a piece of state value that I need in order to fill the rest of my states?

I currently have my auth: `{ uid = 'XXXZZZYYYY' }..`. I just need to call that like

```
getState().auth.uid
```

however that doesn't work at all.

I tried a lot of different questions, using `mapDispatchToProps`, etc. I can show my repo if needed.

Worth to mention that I tried following this other question without success.
[Accessing Redux state in an action creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667249/accessing-redux-state-in-an-action-creator)
This is my relevant current code:

```
const store = createStore(  
    rootReducer,
    defaultState,
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));
```

And

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    watchFirebase(dispatch); // to dispatch async Firebase calls
    return bindActionCreators(actionCreator, dispatch);
}  
const App = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppWrapper);
```

Which I am exporting correctly as many other `not pure` functions work correctly.
For instance, this works correctly:

```
export function fillLoggedUser() {  
      return (dispatch, getState) => {
      dispatch({
        type: C.LOGGED_IN,
      });
    }
  }
```

However as suggested below, this doesn't do a thing:

```
const logState = () => ( dispatch, getState ) => {  
       console.log(getState());  
  };
```

Comment: as suggested in the SO answer you linked, the simplest way of doing this is to use redux-thunk. If you already tried it please post some code so we can help you on your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

In general your thunked action creator should look something like the below (I have used a post id as an example parameter):

```
const getPost = ( postId ) => ( dispatch, getState ) => {
    const state = getState();
    const authToken = state.reducerName.authToken;
    Api.getPost(postId, authToken)
    .then(result => {
        // where postRetrieved returns an action
        dispatch(postRetrieved(result));
    });
};
```

If this is similar to what you have then I would log your state out and see what is going on with a simple thunk.

```
const logState = () => ( dispatch, getState ) => {
    console.log(getState());
};
```

Comment: This logging doesn't appear to do anything inside my actioncreator.js file. I don't understand why. And I think that's my main problem.

Comment: Is console.log called, but nothing is logged? Or is it never called?

Comment: is never called. Plus, when I tried calling getState() in another way I get that getState() is not a function.