# Is using getState in a Redux Thunk good practice?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk, getstate

I have seen conflicting (or just confusing, to me) answers in other questions here regarding whether using `getState` within an action is acceptable, or not, and I have seen quite a few times it being called an anti-pattern. For me, it seems to work great but what is the best practice for doing this if we are not to use `getState`?

I am using `getState` within a thunk to filter through an array of users that is currently connected to some mock data and being pulled into the state of the application.

Here is the code for my action:

```
export const accountLogInSuccess = user => ({
    type: types.ACCOUNT_LOG_IN_SUCCESS,
    user,
});

export const accountLogOutSuccess = () => ({
    type: types.ACCOUNT_LOG_OUT_SUCCESS,
});

export const accountCheckSuccess = () => ({
    type: types.ACCOUNT_CHECK_SUCCESS,
});

export const accountCheck = () => (
    (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(ajaxCallBegin());
        return apiAccount.accountCheck().then((account) => {
            if (account) {
                const user = findByUID(getState().users, account.uid);
                dispatch(accountLogInSuccess(user));
                toastr.success(`Welcome ${user.nameFirst}!`);
            } else {
                dispatch(accountLogOutSuccess());
            }
            dispatch(accountCheckSuccess());
        }).catch((error) => {
            dispatch(ajaxCallError(error));
            toastr.error(error.message);
            throw (error);
        });
    }
);
```

And my reducer:

```
export default function reducerAccount(state = initial.account, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case types.ACCOUNT_LOG_IN_SUCCESS:
        return Object.assign({}, state, action.user, {
            authenticated: true,
        });
    case types.ACCOUNT_LOG_OUT_SUCCESS:
        return Object.assign({}, {
            authenticated: false,
        });
    case types.ACCOUNT_CHECK_SUCCESS:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            initialized: true,
        });
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

The initial state of account used in my reducer is just:

```
account: {
    initialized: false,
    authenticated: false,
},
```

The `accountCheck` action passes the user (found using `getState` and the `findByUID` function) into `accountLogInSuccess` where the reducer adds its values to the current state of account via `Object.assign`.

Preferring to not have to get the user at the root of my application and then passing it down via props, what is the best practice to accomplish this within Redux and having the user data be available in state? Again, using `getState` within the thunk works great for me thus far, but is there a better solution to this that is not considered an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 46):

I wrote an extended blog post called [Idiomatic Redux: Thoughts on Thunks, Sagas, Abstraction, and Reusability](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/idiomatic-redux-thoughts-on-thunks-sagas-abstraction-and-reusability/), which addresses this topic in detail.  In it, I respond to several critiques of thunks and use of `getState` (including Dan Abramov's comments in [Accessing Redux state in an action creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667249/accessing-redux-state-in-an-action-creator/35674575#35674575)).  In fact, my post was specifically inspired by questions like yours.

As a TL;DR of my post: I believe that thunks are a completely viable tool for use in Redux applications, and encourage their use.  While there are some valid concerns to be aware of when using thunks and sagas, and using `getState/select` inside of them, these concerns should not scare you away from using thunks.

Comment: so is using getState in middleware it bad practice? This answer seems to answer whether using thunks is good practice.

Comment: No, it's not a bad practice, as my blog post says.

Comment: Cool, it'd be nice to put that in the answer, so it's not a link-only answer.

Comment: this is a bad answer as the content exists in ephemeral links.

Comment: @JCraine : not sure what your complaint is here.  For the record, while Dan created Redux, I have been the primary maintainer since mid-2016.  Today [we still teach thunks as the default approach for async logic](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic), and `getState` is a standard part of the thunk API. If it wasn't meant to be used it wouldn't be in there :)

Comment: @JBaczuk Neither OPs question nor markerikson's answer are addressing middlewares. How is this relevant?

Comment: Redux's middleware API was specifically designed so that middleware have access to `getState` and `dispatch`.  Like I said a year ago, we wouldn't have designed middleware to get those functions if you weren't supposed to use them :)