# How to dispatch Redux store data without having to receive it in a React component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

If there is data in Redux store that needs to sent to server by dispatching an async action, how to dispatch it without having to receive it inside of a React component because this data is not used for rendering anything.

Example:

My store:

```
{
  dataNotUsedForRendering: 'A',
  dataUsedForRendering: 'B'
}
```

My component:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    //...

    render(){
        const {dataUsedForRendering, dataNotUsedForRendering, dispatch} = this.props;

     return (
     <div>
        {dataUsedForRendering}
        <button onClick={()=> dispatch({type: 'SAVE', payload: dataNotUsedForRendering})}>Save</button>
     </div>);
    }
}

export const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    dataUsedForRendering: state.dataUsedForRendering,
    dataNotUsedForRendering: state.dataNotUsedForRendering
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Here `dataNotUsedForRendering` is being received as a prop inside MyComponent just for the purpose of sending it to server.

I tried `mapDispatchToProps` but I get the props of `Connect(MyComponent)` and not `MyComponent`.

Comment: redux-thunk have `getState` which can load your entire state in a action. But it is not recommended to load the state that way.

Comment: @TryingToImprove I'm trying to improve (pun intended) and since I'm using `getState` in every action creator the I need data to reach an endpoint (tokens, etc...), I wanted to know why is it not recommended to load the state that way? Which alternative would you recommend? In the past I've created a helper that [`subscribes`](https://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe) to redux's store, and updates [`axios' default headers`](https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults) but I found it too hard to add exceptions to that approach.

Comment: @MaximoDominguez you can use `getState` in your thunk for this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43260654/2479481 There are some concerns with this approach in the community (which you can read about above), but you should feel free to use it if it makes sense for you.

Comment: As @LukeMWillis says, it is a way to load data, but I think that you should try and limit it it's use.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you would accomplish that with redux-thunk. Your component would change so that it knows nothing about `dataNotUsedForRendering`, and imports a `save` action:

```
import { save } from './actions';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {dataUsedForRendering, dispatch} = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                {dataUsedForRendering}
                <button onClick={() => dispatch(save())}>Save</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    dataUsedForRendering: state.dataUsedForRendering
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Then your action:

```
export const save = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'SAVE',
        payload: getState().dataNotUsedForRendering
    });
};
```

---

Edit: but you probably don't need to do this. You could just access/modify your `dataNotUsedForRendering` in your reducer. If you're just grabbing this data out of the store to save it in another section of the state, consider normalizing your store and processing your actions across multiple reducers as appropriate.

Comment: My use case is that I need to send it to server. I use `redux-saga` so perhaps I could import store (the output of `createStore`) and do a `getState` on that.

Comment: @ArjunU I wouldn't recommend that approach. Where is the data coming from? Is it entered into a form or something?

Comment: The data does originate from a form. At any given time only a little of it is rendered or updated but I have to send the whole data to server for every change. Sounds like bad design but it's not for other reasons.

Comment: Just found out that there's a `yield select` API in redux saga to access store

Answer (score 1):

Redux saga equivalent of [@LukeMWillis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48630383/2251156):

```
const selectDataNotUsedForRendering = state => state.dataNotUsedForRendering;

const dataNotUsedForRendering = yield select(selectDataNotUsedForRendering);

yield put({
  type: 'SAVE',
  payload: dataNotUsedForRendering
});
```