# In Redux, what is the best way to post data to a server?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-promise-middleware

I want to post data to a server.. my action is like this:

```
export function addNewTodo(text) {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_NEW_TODO',
    payload: addNewTodoApi(text)
  };
}

let addNewTodoApi = function(text) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //implement fake method for get data from server
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve({
        text:     text,
        done:     ??,
        assignTo: ??,
        Project:  ??,
        Category: ??,
        id:       ??
      });
    }, 10);
  });
};
```

I have three way. The first way is import store and and call getState method in my action and the second way is dispatch action in reducer and the last way is pass all data in my action as argument. Which one is correct? I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667249/accessing-redux-state-in-an-action-creator) and I'm worried about antipatterns.

Comment: Not sure about the benefits of using setTimeout in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using `import { connect } from 'react-redux'` and using `containers`.

You access your store on function `mapStateToProps`, you send all your data for your action from the container.

The signature for it is

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {}
```

There you get the `state` which a part could be passed to your action.

The action perform post to your api using ajax with data you passed from state.

In your action your could consider using `isomorphic-fetch`.

Quick example:

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch'

const postData = ()=> ({
  type: types.POST_YOURACTION,
  payload: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(api.postData(), {method: 'POST', }).then(response => {
      resolve(response.json())
    })
  })
})
```

In case if you need to access the store directly you could use `.getState()`, accessing state directly could be considered an anti-pattern but it really depends on your architecture design.
I would suggest to look look at `mapStateToProps`.

Example of how to access your store.

```
import store from 'app/store'
store.getState().yourReducer.data
```

Comment: thanks for your response but my question is how can i access to store in this action?

Comment: @hosseinderakhshan just load your store and use store.getState();

Comment: is access store in action is anti-pattern? please read this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667249/accessing-redux-state-in-an-action-creator

Answer (score 0):

I always use the third way, pass data to the action. The data can be the data in store.getState() or from params or whatever you need to get data from server.