# Form states in react redux

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, create-react-app, react-redux-form

I am a beginner in React ecosystem and I am having a go with forms in React, building a login form with two fields - email and password.

I am maintaining my entire form state in redux . For e.g :

```
const defaultState = { 
    touched: { email: false, password: false },
    loginFormErrors: {email: '', password: ''},
    emailValid: false,
    passwordValid: false,
    formValid: false
}
```

Some of these state values get updated by `validateLoginFields` (reducer) which gets invoked when VALIDATE_LOGIN_FIELDS action is dispatched

```
const validateLoginFields = (state, action) => {
  const newLoginFormErrors = {}
  let emailValid = state.emailValid
  let passwordValid = state.passwordValid
  let formValid = state.formValid

  switch(action.key) {
    case 'email':
    if(!action.value){
        emailValid = false
        newLoginFormErrors.email = ''
    }else{
        const pattern = new RegExp("[^\\s@]+@[^@\\s]+\\.[^@\\s]+")
        emailValid = pattern.test(action.value)
        newLoginFormErrors.email = emailValid ? '' : 'Invalid email'
    }
    break
    case 'password':
    if(!action.value){
        passwordValid = false
        newLoginFormErrors.password = ''
    }else{
        passwordValid = action.value.length >= 6
        newLoginFormErrors.password = passwordValid ? '': 'Password is too short!';
    }
    break
    default:
    break
  }

  formValid = emailValid && passwordValid
  const loginFormErrorData = {}
  Object.assign(loginFormErrorData, state.loginFormErrors, newLoginFormErrors)
  const newState = {}
  Object.assign(newState, state, { loginFormErrors: loginFormErrorData, emailValid: emailValid, passwordValid: passwordValid, formValid: formValid })
  return newState
}
```

I have few questions here :

1. Am I doing the right thing by maintaining client side validation details of my form (e.g valid, touched, formErrors etc) in Redux , or I am better of using local state for this purpose? Since I also store auth related data  in redux, I just felt a little more comfortable by having Redux as my single source of truth for everything , but still want to validate this idea with rest of the community.
2. Whether is it ok for a reducer function like `validateLoginFields` to perform client side validations like I have shown in my example ? It does returns a new state - which is what a reducer does but this function is also performing validations for me... I feel something is wrong here and can be done in a better way ..I mean a more generalised validation? Is reducer the right place for validation like these?

So far I am struggling with client side validations and can't seem to figure out how should I structure my validator in a generic way so that I can scale it when my application grows big. Will be really thankful to community for any ideas on this.

I did try using Redux-form and React-redux-form , these libraries are great but just want to perform these validations on my own for now for learning purpose.

**UPDATE :**

I changed my actionCreator to look like this instead of doing all the validations in reducer. Still I can't seem to figure out where and how should I have my validations in shared way so that other email and password fields in my application can access this logic, not just the login component.

```
export function validateLoginFields(key, value) {
  const newLoginFormErrors = {}
  let emailValid = false
  let passwordValid = false
  let formValid = false

  switch(key) {
    case 'email':
    if(!value){
      emailValid = false
      newLoginFormErrors.email = ''
    }else{
      const pattern = new RegExp("[^\\s@]+@[^@\\s]+\\.[^@\\s]+")
      emailValid = pattern.test(value)
      newLoginFormErrors.email = emailValid ? '' : 'Invalid email'
    }
    break
    case 'password':
    if(!value){
      passwordValid = false
      newLoginFormErrors.password = ''
    }else{
      passwordValid = value.length >= 6
      newLoginFormErrors.password = passwordValid ? '': 'Password is too short!';
    }
    break
    default:
    break
  }

  formValid = emailValid && passwordValid

  return { type: VALIDATE_LOGIN_FIELDS, newLoginFormErrors, emailValid, passwordValid, formValid }
}
```

With the above change, I have put myself in an another issue where I am returning `emailValid=false`, even if I am validating password field. If in my previous state `emailValid=true` then it becomes false. This is happening because I override my state values. Is there any way I can access the current state in actionCreator so that I can return the same state values if nothing has changed?

But, as per this post accessing the state in actionCreator is not the best way..

[Accessing Redux state in an action creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667249/accessing-redux-state-in-an-action-creator)

Comment: I would put the validation in the actionCreator(). Usually, reducers just take a new state as a parameter and do nothing more

Answer (score 3):

I put my validation in my reducers. Reducers take the previous state and an action and then return a new state.

Here's the structure of a simple store:

```
{customer: {
  firstName: "FatBoy",
  lastName: "Slim",
  email: 'foo@bar.com',
  validationErrors: {}
}}
```

Here's a reducer that updates the customer and does validation of the email address:

```
function customerReducer(state = {}, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
     case 'UPDATE_CUSTOMER':
       let validationErrors = {}
       let emailError = validateEmail(action.customer.email);
       if (emailError) {
         validationErrors['email'] = emailError;
       }   
       return {...state, ...action.customer, validationErrors};
     default:
       return state;
   }
}
```

(Note. This is pseudo-code. It has never been run by anyone ever. It's there for you to get the gist.)

To me, the reducer is the logical place to put your validation. They way I think of it is that the action creator's job is to send the *minimum* state necessary to update the store, while the reducer's job is to transform that state into the *optimal* state needed by the application. And I'm the sort of guy who thinks that validation is optimal, so I do that in my reducers.

Comment: This is pretty cool. The redux-form alternative is much more complicated.

Comment: This looks not ideal to me.Validation will happen after any calls to server: we put AJAX calls in ActionCreators (async) and they stand before the Reducer in the Redux Flow - and usually validation should be done before any AJAX requests.