# Using Redux, is it a bad practice to cancel a previous action in an action creator?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am creating a validator for a field and triggering validation on update. I only care about the validation result of the current state. So if another update is triggered before the validation completes, I don't want the validation success to occur for the old piece of data.

I have read and believe that accessing the store in an action creator is somewhat of an anti-pattern in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674575/816584.

I currently have the following:

```js
export const USERNAME_VALIDATION_PENDING = 'USERNAME_VALIDATION_PENDING';
export const USERNAME_VALIDATION_SUCCESS = 'USERNAME_VALIDATION_SUCCESS';
export const USERNAME_VALIDATION_FAILURE = 'USERNAME_VALIDATION_FAILURE';
export const USERNAME_VALIDATION_ABORTED = 'USERNAME_VALIDATION_PENDING';

export interface Validator {
    validate(subject: string): Promise<void, Error>;
    cancel();
}

const cache = new WeakMap();

function memoize(obj: {}, subject: string, result: Error | true) {
    const map: {[subject: string]: Error | true} = cache.has(obj) ?
        cache.get(obj) : {};

    // TODO: Do consider caching just the message so the stack can get GC
    map[subject] = result;
    cache.set(obj, map);
}

function resultCacheP(obj: {}, subject: string) {
    const map: {[subject: string]: Error | true} = cache.has(obj) ?
        cache.get(obj) : {};
    return Object.keys(map).indexOf(subject) !== -1;
}

function resultCache(obj: {}, subject: string) {
    const map: {[subject: string]: Error | true} = cache.has(obj) ?
        cache.get(obj) : {};

    return map[subject];
}

export function requestUsernameValidation(username: string, validator: Validator) {
    return {
        type: USERNAME_VALIDATION_PENDING,
        isValidating: true,
        isValid: false,
        username,
        validator,
    }
}

export function receiveUsernameValidationSuccess() {
    return {
        type: USERNAME_VALIDATION_SUCCESS,
        isValidating: false,
        isValid: true,
    }
}

export function receiveUsernameValidationFailure(error: string) {
    return {
        type: USERNAME_VALIDATION_FAILURE,
        isValidating: false,
        isValid: false,
        error,
    }
}

export function validateUsername(username: string, validator: Validator) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(requestUsernameValidation(username, validator));

        if (resultCacheP(validator, username)) {
            const result = resultCache(validator, username);
            if (result instanceof Error) {
                dispatch(receiveUsernameValidationSuccess());
            } else {
                dispatch(receiveUsernameValidationFailure(result.message));
            }
        } else {
            validator.validate(username)
                .then(() => {
                    memoize(validator, username, true);
                    dispatch(receiveUsernameValidationSuccess());
                })
                .catch((err: Error) => {
                    memoize(validator, username, err);
                    dispatch(receiveUsernameValidationFailure(err.message));
                });
        }
    };
}
```

I would like for the `requestUsernameValidation` to call cancel on the validator from the previous action if my state is currently validating to avoid a race condition where the previous validator finishes later and incorrectly updates the state.

I think I need to change `requestUsernameValidation` to a thunk to get the current state.

This is my first attempt at using Redux. Most tutorials I've read have really lean action creators, but a lot of real world projects I've seen have a lot of complex logic in them. Is this approach the correct way to solve this?

Comment: Dan's opinion is that accessing state in action creators is usually bad, but I disagree.  See my blog post [Idiomatic Redux: Thoughts on Thunks, Sagas, Abstraction, and Reusability](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/idiomatic-redux-thoughts-on-thunks-sagas-abstraction-and-reusability/) for discussion of the pros and cons of doing so.

Comment: @markerikson moving state transformations into what feels like a glorified global terrifies me. I've taken the approach of using action creators to log changes, and using thunks when a guided sequence of actions is necessary (usually due to branching). Then with reducers I can take the sequence of state changes to reproduce state at any point in time. Is that an appropriate use of Redux?

Comment: Not quite sure I follow your comment. Yes, in one sense, Redux _is_ a "glorified global", but it also provides a pattern for separating "write logic" from the rest of the app. Can you maybe give a specific example of what concerns you have, and what you're doing now? Also, per your original question, I'm not sure what you mean by "cancel a previous action". Out of the box, calling `dispatch(someActionObject)` is synchronous - by the time it returns, the root reducer has run, and the state has been updated, so there's nothing to cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Usually with input fields i would go with using a `debounce` method:

Quoting https://github.com/component/debounce

> Creates and returns a new debounced version of the passed function that will postpone its execution until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time it was invoked.

for example if you do

```
let waitTime = 300;
const debouncedValidateUsername = debounce((username, validator) => dispatch => { ... })
```

The validation will happen only 300 milliseconds after the last change and you will have the latest user `input`

**UPDATE**

Inspired by this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233302/promise-is-it-possible-to-force-cancel-a-promise) you can do the following

```
let cancellationAmbassador = {
  cancel() {}
};

function validate(validator, username, cancellationAmbassador) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    validator
      .validate(username)
      .then(() => {
        resolve("valid");
      })
      .catch((err: Error) => {
        reject("invalid");
      });
    cancellationAmbassador.cancel = function() {
      reject("cancellation");
    };
  });
}

export function validateUsername(username: string, validator: Validator) {
  return dispatch => {
    cancellationAmbassador.cancel();
    dispatch(requestUsernameValidation(username, validator));
    if (resultCacheP(validator, username)) {
      const result = resultCache(validator, username);
      if (result instanceof Error) {
        dispatch(receiveUsernameValidationSuccess());
      } else {
        dispatch(receiveUsernameValidationFailure(result.message));
      }
    } else {
      validate(validator, username, cancellationAmbassador)
        .then(() => {
          memoize(validator, username, true);
          dispatch(receiveUsernameValidationSuccess());
        })
        .catch(reason => {
          if (reason !== "cancellation") {
            memoize(validator, username, err);
            dispatch(receiveUsernameValidationFailure(err.message));
          }
        });
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Good thing to consider. But that still doesn't provide a safeguard against a previous validation succeeding after a successor. It just reduces the likelihood of collision assuming I can guess the magic number to wait for lambda post processing of dynamo query on an unknown number of records

Comment: Ok i did some searching (got me interested your question) and i updated the answer to what might be a better fit for your case! you could actually combine both methods

Comment: That would work, thank you. Also, looking in to the debounce suggestion. Your provided snipped passes in an anonymous function which would be a different object created each time, so if I read the implementation correctly it would just delay the call 300ms.

Comment: Oh, I see, it returns a function like bind.