# react-redux with thunk - getState is not a function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, react-redux, getstate

I'm currently receiving the error TypeError: getState is not a function
I'm attempting something similar to the example at http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

action.js - error occurs here

```
export const fetchCategoriesIfNeeded = (dispatch, getState) => {
    if(shouldFetchCategories(getState())){
        return dispatch(fetchCategories())
    }
}
```

App.js

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.dispatch(fetchCategoriesIfNeeded())
  }
```

...

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    isFetching: state.isFetching,
    categories: state.categories
    }
}
```

reducer.js

```
function data (state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case RECEIVE_CATEGORIES:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                categories: action.categories
            }
        case REQUEST_CATEGORIES:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: true
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
    return state
}
```

omitted some of the code for readability.

I've also tried this and receive TypeError: dispatch is not a function

```
export function fetchCategoriesIfNeeded(){
    return(dispatch, getState) =>{
        var state = getState()
        if(shouldFetchCategories(state)){
            dispatch(fetchCategories())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you're not passing anything into fetchCategoriesIfNeeded when you call it, so it makes sense it would flail when it tries to call getState.

Comment: I'm guessing (we can't see `this.props.dispatch` but the name leads me to believe) that you meant `this.props.dispatch(fetchCategoriesIfNeeded)`

Comment: I'm using thunk middleware. I changed my code slightly but now it says dispatch is not a function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667249/accessing-redux-state-in-an-action-creator

Answer (score 5):

Change

`export const fetchCategoriesIfNeeded = (dispatch, getState) => {`

to

`export const fetchCategoriesIfNeeded = () => (dispatch, getState) => {`

Your action creator needs to return either an action (aka an object with a `type` key) or function (courtesy of redux-thunk). Your function signature had you passing in two parameters, `dispatch` and `getState` while the second function signature takes no parameters but the return function does take `dispatch` and `getState`, which are provided by redux-thunk.

You could also write it out to avoid confusion like so

```js
export const fetchCategoriesIfNeeded = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
       // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing something weird with how you're calling the dispatch.

You should be using a `mapDispatchToProps` function as well.

eg. something like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => {
   return {
       onUpdate: dispatch(fetchCategories())
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    isFetching: state.isFetching,
    categories: state.categories
    }
}
```

and:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.onUpdate(); 
  }
```