# redux-thunk old data coming after switching routes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, redux, redux-thunk

I am trying redux-thunk and when I fetch the API (with delay of 5s to test) from Route1, the go to Route2 and back to Route1, within that time I receive the first request I made that at this point is old. How can I solve that issue?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973117/redux-thunk-how-to-prevent-it-from-making-unnecessary-api-request

Comment: @keikai I think that it talk about an unnecessary call or some caché, is not about this case of concurrency