# Accessing state in a Redux action

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a Redux reducer with the following state:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  permissions: [''],
  authzError: null
};
```

I already have some Redux actions that modify state.permissions. I am writing the following action to run permission checks:

```
export function isAuthz(allowed, except) {
  // I need state.permissions here
  ...
}
```

I know I can do this:

```
export function isAuthz(allowed, except, permissions) {
  // Now do permission check
  ...
}
```

But this means pulling state.permissions out in the component and then putting it in the isAuthz action, which seems like a waste and error prone. I could just check permissions in the reducer, but I thought an action is where I am suppose to do this.

Where should I do this permission check and how do I get a hold of state.permissions ?

Thanks,

Warren

Comment: If it's something that can be calculated from `state.permissions`, then there is no reason for it to be in `state`. You can just extract that to a function and calculate it dynamically. For example in `connect`.

Comment: Also, if you are using redux-thunk, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667249/accessing-redux-state-in-an-action-creator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the state in your actions too.

For example in this action you can do this:

```
export function isAuthz(allowed, except) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState()
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: You need redux-thunk for this or not ?

Answer (score 4):

if you're exporting your store from a module

`export default createStore(...)`

just import it

```
import store from '../path/to/store'

export function isAuthz() {
  const state = store.getState()
  ... // use state.permission
}
```

edit: as others have pointed out, if you're using `redux-thunk`, a `getState` argument is provided to you as the second param in the thunk

```
export function isAuthz(...) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    const { permission } = getState()
  }
}
```

Comment: I was too quick to post. A few more minutes and I had the answer.

Comment: :D always good to put these things online to help others, though.

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer right after I post the question. You can use redux-thunk to get the state.

```
export function isAuthz(allowed, except) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
     const { permissions } = getState();
     // Now do permission check
  };
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Warren