# Redux getState in action not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I'm getting a bit confused with getState() in redux. I am using the thunk middleware.

I have an auth action which is an async action. But I have an action which runs before which checks if a token exists in state and if its still valid.

My problem is i can't seem to check the state when I have called the action. Thought I could just use getState but that doesn't seem to be a function.

container.js

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.authCheck()
}
...
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    authCheck: () => checkApiStatus()(dispatch)
  }
}
```

Action.js

```
export const checkApiStatus = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const expires_at = getState().api.expires_at
  if (!expires_at || isDateGreater(expires_at)) {
    // dispatch async action
    dispatch(apiAuth())
  }
  return
}
```

Anyone have any ideas. Or perhaps better way of implementing something like this?

Thanks

Comment: I guess I could just add authCheck: () => checkApiStatus()(dispatch, store.getStore) and import the store to the container. It looks like Im doing something wrong though.

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out too. Here is a popular related question about thunks: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35667249/470749

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you explicitly calling the returned function in you `mapDispatchToProps` method and passing only one argument. Instead call `dispatch(checkApiStatus())` then redux-thunk will take care of passing the right arguments to the returned method. Should look like this

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    authCheck: () => dispatch(checkApiStatus())
  }
}
```