# How to get data from redux in Actions?

Tags: react-native, redux

I am trying to understand if there is a way to call data from redux in an Action.

Here is my action where I want to use user_id and token which are stored in state.auth.user_id and state.auth.token

jobsActions.js

```
export function createJob(title, company, avatar, shortDescription, description, address, postcode, city, jobType, payment, price, duration, postDate ) {
  return function (dispatch) {
      return axios.post(JOBS_URL(user_id), { title, company, avatar, shortDescription, description, address, postcode, city, jobType, payment, price, duration, postDate }, {
        headers: { authorization: token }
      }).then((response) => {
        dispatch(addJob(response.data.job));
        // console.log(response.data.job)
      }).catch((err) => {
        // console.log(err);
        dispatch(addAlert("Couldn't create job."));
      });
  };
}
```

authAction.js

```
export function loginUser(email, password) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return axios.post(SIGNIN_URL, { email, password }).then((response) => {
      var { user_id, token } = response.data;
      dispatch(authUser(user_id, token));
      onSignIn(user_id);
    }).catch((error) => {
      dispatch(addAlert("Could not log in."));
    });
  };
}

export const authUser = (user_id, token) => {
  return {
    type: 'AUTH_USER',
    user_id,
    token
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing Redux state in an action creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667249/accessing-redux-state-in-an-action-creator)

Comment: @HenrikAndersson Whats the duplicate in this? I have already dispatched the the user_id and token from authAction.js and now I need to use them in jobsAction.js see the edit

Comment: Exactly, you want to access your stores data inside an action creator, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You're using `redux-thunk`, and thunk functions already get `getState` as the second argument.  Just change your functions to:

```
export function createJob(title, company, avatar, shortDescription, description, address, postcode, city, jobType, payment, price, duration, postDate ) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
      const state = getState();
      const {user_id, token} = state.auth;

      return axios.post(JOBS_URL(user_id), { title, company, avatar, shortDescription, description, address, postcode, city, jobType, payment, price, duration, postDate }, {
        headers: { authorization: token }
      }).then((response) => {
        dispatch(addJob(response.data.job));
        // console.log(response.data.job)
      }).catch((err) => {
        // console.log(err);
        dispatch(addAlert("Couldn't create job."));
      });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before and created an enhancer to help handle it:

[redux-named-reducers](https://github.com/mileschristian/redux-named-reducers)

It allows state access from anywhere in your code and to link reducer states to each other.  For example, using the enchancer your job reducer can have an read-only external state called token linked to your auth reducer's token:

```
linkState(jobReducer.token, authReducer.token)
```

Later you can access the token from your action

```
createJob() {
   ...
   var token = getState(jobReducer.token)
}
```

The advantage of this is your job module does not care where the token comes from.  You can easily swap authentication methods from different modules:

```
swith(loginType) {
    case USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD:
       linkState(jobReducer.token, authReducer.token)
    break;
    case FACEBOOK_LOGIN:
       linkState(jobReducer.token, facebookReducer.token)
    break;
    case OAUTH:
       linkState(jobReducer.token, oauthReducer.token)
    break
}
```