# Pass a state value from redux reducer to another reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I wanna pass a value from redux state from reducer to another reducer. In my case i want to pass the value of `groups` from state in `groupReducer.js` to `scheduleReducer.js`. I'm using `combineReducers` from `redux` to combine between them.

Here's my code:
 `groupReducer.js`

```
...
const initialState = {
groups: [],
...
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case FETCH_GROUPS:
    return {
      ...state,
      groups: action.payload
    };
...
```

`scheduleReducer.js`

```
const initialState = {
  ...
}
...
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case GROUP_INFO:
    return {
      group: groupInfo(action.payload.id, SHOULD_PASS_GROUPS_FETCHED_FROM_GROUPREDUCER)
    };
```

I want to pass the `groups` to the last reducer, How can i do this?

Comment: are you using redux-thunk?

Comment: yes i'm using redux-thunk

Comment: then you can pass required data from action creator as an additional payload

Comment: How can i do this?
`return dispatch({
        type: GROUP_INFO,
        payload: response.data
      });
` and the other depends on the type too.

Comment: Consider using a Thunk action to share your reducer's values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667249/accessing-redux-state-in-an-action-creator

Answer (score 2):

You can use thunk to access complete `state` object. Get groups from `groupReducer` and then call your action `SHOULD_PASS_GROUPS_FETCHED_FROM_GROUPREDUCER` to pass those groups to `sheduleReducer`.

```
// thunk action creator, use it as a normal action creator     //
//  while dispatching                                            //
function passGroupFetchedFromGroupReducer() {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {

    // Get state object from getState(). Try console.log(getState() to get 
    // idea of the shape of what getState() returns.

    const groupsToPass = getState().groupReducer.groups;

    // Then dispatch your action with the payload
    dispatch({
     type: 'SHOULD_PASS_GROUPS_FETCHED_FROM_GROUPREDUCER',
     payload: groupsToPass
    })
  };
}

// scheduleReducer.js //
const initialState = {
  groups: [],
  ...
}
...
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case GROUP_INFO:
    return {
      ...state,
      groups: action.payload
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.
Get your app's state in action creator and then access the group reducer's state to get `groups`

```
const getGroupInfo = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const appState = getState();
  const groups = appState.groupReducerKey.groups;
  // code...

  dispatch({
    type: ' GROUP_INFO',
    payload: {
      id:'',
      // any other data
      groups: groups,
    },
  });
};


// scheduleReducer.js
const initialState = {
  ...
}
...
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case GROUP_INFO:
  // access here 
  // action.payload.groups
    return {
      group: groupInfo(action.payload.id, action.payload.groups)
    };
  }
}
```

I suggest reading more about sharing data between reducers in redux docs: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/beyondcombinereducers#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers