# Redux ged Id from store to action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I need to get the id of a user from the store to my action is there a way how to make it correct because this is the way how I using it but I think it's not correct is there a better way how to make this.

this is my action

```
export const editNote = (note, userId)=> {
  
    return async dispatch => {
      await axios.put(`http://localhost:8080/api/user/${userId}/note`, note
        )
            .then(response => {
                console.log("response from note api", response.body)
            })
            .catch(e => console.log(e))
    }
}
```

and this is how I called id

```
  const reducer = useSelector(state => state.user);

    const onSubmit = values => {
        console.log(values)
        dispatch(editNote(values, reducer.id))
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674575/11218031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In actions you can pass `getState` parameter as same as you pass dispatch parameter to action.
So your action like this (example):

```
export const editNote = (note, userId) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    user = getState().user;
  }
}
```

with this code: `user = getState().user` you can access to the user and with `getState()` you can access to all your stored data in redux. (like state param in mapStateToProps function or useSelector hook in components)