# How to get a particular state value in React Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

In Redux, I currently have a state that looks something like the following.

```
{
  activeConversation: "Jim"
  conversations: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  user: {id: 8, username: "josh", email: ""}
}
```

I currently have a function that adds a new message to the conversations array. Here's how it works; it starts by calling it in `thunk`.

```
export const postMessage = (body) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
      if (!body.conversationId) {
        dispatch(addConversation(body.recipientId, data.message));
      } else {
        dispatch(setNewMessage(data.message));
      }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

If the `conversationId` exists then it calls `setNewMessage` in `Actions`.

```
const SET_MESSAGE = "SET_MESSAGE";
export const setNewMessage = (message, sender) => {
  return {
    type: SET_MESSAGE,
    payload: { message, sender: sender || null },
  };
};

const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_MESSAGE:
      return addMessageToStore(state, action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

The problem is that the state in this action only contains the conversations array and not anything else. What I need is to also have the `activeConversation` so I can use it in my reducer function. I'm not quite sure how states work so I don't know why only the conversations array appears in `state` and not anything else.

Also, here's how `activeConversation` is being set.

```
const SET_ACTIVE_CHAT = "SET_ACTIVE_CHAT";

export const setActiveChat = (username) => {
  return {
    type: SET_ACTIVE_CHAT,
    username
  };
};

const reducer = (state = "", action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_ACTIVE_CHAT: {
      return action.username;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I'm wondering how I can get the `activeConversation` state for my set message reducer function.

Comment: Actions don't have state, but I think I understand. It sounds like you want to reference both the `activeConversation` ***and*** the `conversations` array within the same reducer function. For this the state and reducer functions should be combined, in other words, you might've split up your state a little too much. Can you describe in some detail how you want to merge and use these two state?

Comment: Do you have root reducer where you combine the positions of states you make in your reduces?

Comment: I believe I do. Should I just be using that or is there a way I can combine multiple states?

Comment: As @DrewReese pointed out you need to combine the state or another approach is to pass the `activeConversation` as a payload . so that inside the reducer you can do `action.payload.activeConversation` .

Comment: I don't necessarily want to pass it in from thunk because I need to know what the current state of ```activeConversation``` is at that particular point. I was wondering if there was a way to access the state of ```activeConversation``` from within my reducer function (note that I already imported the ```activeConversation``` reducer).

Answer (score 0):

`Thunk` will give you access to the entire store as the second argument using the method `getState`. So you can change your action creator as

```
export const postMessage = (body) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    if (!body.conversationId) {
      dispatch(addConversation(body.recipientId, data.message));
    } else {
      const { activeConversation } = getState();
      dispatch(setNewMessage(data.message, activeConversation));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Pass the state as the payload to your action object .

```
export const setNewMessage = (message, activeConversation, sender) => {
  return {
    type: SET_MESSAGE,
    payload: { message, activeConversation, sender: sender || null },
  };
};
```

Once you have it in the action payload , you can read it inside your reducer as `action.payload.activeConversation`

The getState() method provided by thunk will guarantee the store state at that particular point in time . As it interally is just the call to `store.getState()` provided by redux .

Reference

[Thunk getState](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#motivation)

[Accessing getState in action creator](https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#how-do-i-share-state-between-two-reducers-do-i-have-to-use-combinereducers)

[Good explanation on accessing getState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667249/accessing-redux-state-in-an-action-creator)

Comment: While that does get me the correct state, what I'm doing is a chat app that sends messages to another user. So, after the call in thunk, I then call ```sendMessage(data, body);`` that uses socket.io to send the data to the other user. On socket.io, it would then call ```store.dispatch(setNewMessage(data.message, data.sender))``` and if I pass in the state I got from thunk, I'm wondering if it would be the correct state for the other user.

Comment: @JoshSusa give it a shot , we will not know until we try it :-)

Comment: Does your `activeConversation` inside your thunk has any value ? . I would suggest you to check in the Redux dev tools as well whether we are seeing the `activeConversation` in the state when dispatching the action .

Comment: Alright, I got it working but it's still the same active user for both sides. I want the active user to be different for each user. Is it possible to get the state from my conversations reducer?