# react, redux chain a next dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm still beginning in react and redux and now I followed this [tutorial](http://medium.com/front-end-developers/handcrafting-an-isomorphic-redux-application-with-love-40ada4468af4) and it uses this [middleware](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/99#issuecomment-112212639) for dispatch. I was wondering how I would do another dispatch after the first one (to chain it)? I have something like this now.

```
fetchData() {
  const { dispatch } = this.props;
  const action = PageActions.fetchPage({slug: this.props.params.slug});
  dispatch(action);
}
```

and wondering if I can `dispatch(action).then(...)` but the return of `dispatch` is always undefined. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.
It's solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50208749/why-dont-chaining-dispatch-redux-thunk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to use async actions inside of your action creators you need to use middleware. The recommended middleware is `thunk`.

There is a good post on Stack about it's usage and appropriate situations. [Stack Overflow Async Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout/35415559#35415559)

This will allow you to dispatch many actions from a single action. However if you are wanting to "chain" actions together you should simply dispatch the second action at the end of the first actions definition.

ie

```
function getBookings() {
  return (
    RequestHelper.fetchEntities(Routes.bookings.all, {}, queryParams)
      .then(res => dispatch(getBookingsSuccess(res));
  )
}

...
function getBookingsSuccess(data) {
  dispatch(showSuccess());
}
```

Comment: If I do use `redux-thunk`, do I need to remove my existing promiseMiddleware? If I don't, how should I chain the next one in my action creators? Adding `.then` to my usual actions doesn't work eg. `return { type: FETCH, promise: request.get(...)[.then(...)]}`. Both does do the request I can see on the server but my app fails though.

Comment: So I used and learened thunk to accomplish this. Thanks!