# Why don't chaining dispatch Redux-Thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, react-thunk

Why don't chaining dispatch Redux Thunk? Only work first dispatch and second dispatch is not working.

Store:

```js
const store = createStore(reducers, loadState(), applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Action:

```js
export function doSomething(name) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({
            type: 'USERNAME',
            payload: name
        })
        dispatch({
            type: 'OTHER_TYPE',
            payload: 'text'
        })

         return true;
    }
}
```

**Edit**
It's worked:

```js
return Promise.all([
        dispatch({
            type: 'USERNAME',
            payload: name
        }),
        dispatch({
            type: 'OTHER_TYPE',
            payload: 'text'
        })
    ])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk):

```js
    // We can dispatch both plain object actions and other thunks,
    // which lets us compose the asynchronous actions in a single flow.

    return dispatch(
      makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('My Grandma')
    ).then(() =>
      Promise.all([
        dispatch(makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('Me')),
        dispatch(makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('My wife'))
      ])
    ).then(() =>
      dispatch(makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('Our kids'))
    ).then(() =>
      dispatch(getState().myMoney > 42 ?
        withdrawMoney(42) :
        apologize('Me', 'The Sandwich Shop')
      )
    );
```

> But I would recommend using [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) instead of redux-thunk
>   because of [these](http://blog.jakegardner.me/redux-thunk-vs-saga/) reasons.

Comment: How does Redux-Saga do this job?

Comment: @mrkacan hope this will help https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-redux-saga-from-action-creators-to-sagas-2587298b5e71