# how to call another reducer method with redux react

Tags: reactjs, redux

Reducer 1 code is as below. I want to call another reducer method after successful authetication of user. so its based of response of reducer 1 , I want to call method/action of reducer 2.

```
const LOGIN = 'redux-example/auth/LOGIN';
const LOGIN_SUCCESS = 'redux-example/auth/LOGIN_SUCCESS';
const LOGIN_FAIL = 'redux-example/auth/LOGIN_FAIL'; 
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { apiurl } from '../../Constants';

import {savedata} from '../../redux/modules/new';

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
switch (action.type) {    
case LOGIN:
  return {
    ...state,
    loggingIn: true
  };
case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    loggingIn: false,
    user: action.result
  };
case LOGIN_FAIL:
  return {
    ...state,
    loggingIn: false,
    user: null,
    loginError: action.error
  };
default:
  return state;
}
}

export function login(page,email,password) {
var querystring = require('querystring');
if(action == undefined) action = null;
var data = querystring.stringify({
    email: email,
    password: password
});
return {
    types: [LOGIN, LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAIL],
    promise: (client) => client.post(apiurl + 'ajax/login', {
       data: data
    }).then(response => {
        //console.log(response);
        switch(page){
            case 'signin':
                if(response.auth == 'true') {
                    redirectuser(response);
                }
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
        return response;
    })
    .catch( error => Promise.reject(error))
};
```

}

```
export  function  redirectuser(response) {
console.log('response is as below');
console.log(response);
if(response.action == 'action1'){
    savedata();
    // here I want call another reducer method save data
}
}
```

When I call action save data of reducer 2 from reducer 1 , it does not work. How to dispatch action of reducer 2 from reducer 1.

Edit 1: my middleware code is as below

```
export default function clientMiddleware(client) {
return ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
if (typeof action === 'function') {
  return action(dispatch, getState);
}

const { promise, types, ...rest } = action; // eslint-disable-line no-redeclare
if (!promise) {
    return next(action);
}

const [REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE] = types;
next({ ...rest, type: REQUEST });

const actionPromise = promise(client, dispatch);
actionPromise.then(
  result => next({ ...rest, result, type: SUCCESS }),
  error => next({ ...rest, error, type: FAILURE })
).catch(error => {
  next({ ...rest, error, type: FAILURE });
});

return actionPromise;
};
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your problem but calling an action from a reducer is an anti pattern and should be avoided, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36731119/3407732 What you may want to do it dispatch the second action, triggering the second reducer inside the component that will be updated by the first action, inside of the componentWillRecieveProps method https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Answer (score -1):

Dispatching an action inside a reducer is not a good move. As i understand, you have to do some update synchronously. One way is, once the first reducer is updated, where ever your are consuming that reducer go and inside componentWillReceiveProps or componentDidUpdate do something like.
NOTE: before dispatching you have to import the configurestore and create a const dispatch from store.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)
 {
  //only if user was not there previously and now user is there
     if(!this.props.user && nextProps.user)
      {
         dispatch({type: SECOND_ACTION, payLoad})
     }
 }
```