# ReactJS: How to handle Image / File upload with Formik?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reducers, formik

I am designing a profile page for my site using `ReactJS`. 
Now my question is how do I upload the image from local machine and save it to the database and also displaying it in the profile page

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { AccountAction } from '../../actions/user/AccountPg1Action';
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

class AccountInfo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props) 
    this.state = {
      currentStep: 1,
      userAccountData: {
        userid: '',
        useravtar: '',
        attachement_id: '',
   }
  }
 }

handleFileUpload = (event) => {
  this.setState({useravtar: event.currentTarget.files[0]})
};

handleChange = event => {
    const {name, value} = event.target
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })    
  }

handleSubmit = event => {
    let that = this;
    const { AccountAction } = that.props;
    event.preventDefault();

    let accountInputs = {
      userid: 49,
      useravtar: that.state.image,
      attachement_id: 478,
}
    that.setState({
      userAccountData: accountInputs,
    })

    AccountAction(accountInputs)
  }
AccountInfoView = () => {
console.log(this.state.useravtar)
    return (
      <section id="account_sec" className="second_form">
      <div className="container">
      <React.Fragment>
        <Formik
          initialValues={‌{
            file: null,
            email: '',
            phone: ''
          }}
          validationSchema={accountInfoSchema}
          render={(values) => {
          return(
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Step1 
          currentStep={this.state.currentStep} 
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          file= {this.state.useravtar}
          handleFileUpload={this.handleFileUpload}
          />
          </Form>
        );
      }}
      />
      </React.Fragment>
      )
  }

  render() {    

    return (
      <div>{this.authView()}</div>
    )
  }
}

function Step1(props) {
console.log(props.useravtar)
  if (props.currentStep !== 1) {
    return null
  } 

  return(
    <div className="upload">
        <label htmlFor="profile">
          <div className="imgbox">
            <img src="images/trans_116X116.png" alt="" />
            <img src={props.useravtar} className="absoImg" alt="" />
          </div>
        </label>
<input id="file" name="file" type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={props.handleFileUpload}/>
        <span className="guide_leb">Add your avatar</span>
      </div>
  )
}
```

When I do console in `handleChange` action for event.target.file[0] it responds with undefined.

Also, doing a `console.log(this.state.useravtar)` in `handleSubmit` action it shows a pathname like `c:/fakepath/imgname.jpg`

P.S: I have a multiple forms so I am using it in a `Step` wise. And i am using Redux Reducer for storing the data.

I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42758040/7995957) link but my requirement is not looking like this.

Comment: have you tried using a form data object - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty : i have used a Formik library so i have used a `Field` component from this library. https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/

Comment: @Taalavya formik doesnot have file upload component, you have to use html input and use ` setFieldValue`  method of formik to set the data

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Formik doesnot support fileupload by default, But you can try the following

```
<input id="file" name="file" type="file" onChange={(event) => {
  setFieldValue("file", event.currentTarget.files[0]);
}} />
```

Here `"file"` represents the key that you are using for holding the file

And on submit you can get the filename, size etc for the file by using

```
onSubmit={(values) => {
        console.log({ 
              fileName: values.file.name, 
              type: values.file.type,
              size: `${values.file.size} bytes`
            })
```

If you want to set the file into components state then you can use

```
onChange={(event) => {
  this.setState({"file": event.currentTarget.files[0]})};
}}
```

According to your code, you have to handle file upload as below

In AccountInfo add a function to handle file upload

```
handleFileUpload = (event) => {
this.setState({WAHTEVETKEYYOUNEED: event.currentTarget.files[0]})};
}
```

And pass the same function to Step1 Component as below

```
    <Step1 
      currentStep={this.state.currentStep} 
      handleChange={this.handleChange}
      file= {this.state.image}
      handleFileUpload={this.handleFileUpload}
      />
```

In Step1 Component where you upload the file, Change the input as

```
<input id="file" name="file" type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={props.handleFileUpload}/>
```

If you need to preview the uploaded image then you can create a blob and pass the same as source for image as below

```
<img src={URL.createObjectURL(FILE_OBJECT)} />
```

**EDIT-1**

As `URL.createObjectURL` method is deprecated due to security issues, we need to use `srcObject` for Media Elements, to use that you can use `ref` to assign srcObject, for example

Assuming you are using class Components,

**Constructor**

in constructor you can use

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.imageElRef = React.createRef(null)
}
```

**HANDLE CHANGE FUNCTION**

```
handleFileUpload = (event) => {
  let reader = new FileReader();
let file = event.target.files[0];
reader.onloadend = () => {
  this.setState({
    file: reader.result
  });
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

**Element**

```
<img src={this.state.file} />
```

Comment: Where to define this `setFieldValue`, it throws me an error of undefined like: 
`./src/components/user/AccountInfo.jsx
  Line 266:  'setFieldValue' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: `setFieldValue` is obtained from `<Formik />`, refer:  https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean-void

Comment: @Taalavya if you want to store the file directly to state you can use the method that i mentioned

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty yess correct but it throws this error from a `function Step1(props){...}` function. https://prnt.sc/np7gnp

Comment: What do u mean by using props.setState...can you update the code with implementation

Comment: @Taalavya Updated my code,According to your implementation, Please check

Comment: yess now i am getting some result. 

So, doing `console.log(this.state.useravtar)` i am getting this result. https://prnt.sc/np84z8

But how can i get a path of uploaded image in for preview ? I did something like this : 

`<img src={props.useravtar} className="absoImg" alt="" />`
`<input id="file" name="file" type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={props.handleFileUpload}/>`

so this `props.useravtar` gives an undefined value for preview image. 

`handleFileUpload = (event) => {
    this.setState({useravtar: event.currentTarget.files[0]})
  };`

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty: can you please update your answer that will be help to other developers also in future.

Comment: Interesting. I'm getting an error when I used `setFieldValue()` the way you suggest, @muthanth. This is the error: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.`

Comment: **createObjectURL** is now deprecated in most of the browsers. I researched it and found that instead of src, we need to use **srcObject**.  But I don't know how to use in <img /> tag. Anyone out there and @SumanthMadishetty Please look into it. It will very helpful for me a lot.

Comment: Thanks, @SumanthMadishetty for the edit. I'm facing an issue which is when I upload the image, my modal refreshes and the file input field lost the value.

Comment: Is there a useFormik example? because I don't think useFormik has a setFieldValue method?

Comment: I get `InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable`  in Firefox. Need to set the input's value to an empty string (based on the error message I got in Chrome) to avoid the error.

Comment: facing this error ==> Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Comment: Yes, as @HassanAliShahzad pointed out, the input value has to be a string. It's better to `setFieldValue('file', e.target.value)` and manage a separate state variable with the file itself - `setFile(reader.result)`.

Answer (score 13):

Here is how I resolved it with **Formik** and **Material UI**

in your JS file, just declare a variable avatarPreview like below

```
  const [avatarPreview, setAvatarPreview] = useState('/avatars/default.png');



           <Box
            display='flex'
            textAlign='center'
            justifyContent='center'
            flexDirection='column'>
           
            <ImageAvatar size='md' src={avatarPreview || user?.avatar} />

            <Button
              variant='contained'
              component='label'
              startIcon={<CloudUploadIcon />}>
              Choose Avatar
              <input
                name='avatar'
                accept='image/*'
                id='contained-button-file'
                type='file'
                hidden
                onChange={(e) => {
                  const fileReader = new FileReader();
                  fileReader.onload = () => {
                    if (fileReader.readyState === 2) {
                      setFieldValue('avatar', fileReader.result);
                      setAvatarPreview(fileReader.result);
                    }
                  };
                  fileReader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
                }}
              />
            </Button>
          </Box>
```

Default Preview:
[image: Default avatar upload]

After choosing avatar:
[image: After you choose your avatar]

Comment: Setting your avatar as the Avatar. ha

Answer (score 4):

You can upload single or multiple files with validation using **Formik** as follows:

```
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage, useField } from "formik";
import axios from "axios";


function App() {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        profile: [],
      }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object({
        profile:Yup.array().min(1,"select at least 1 file")
      })}
      onSubmit={(values, props) => {
        let data = new FormData();
        values.profile.forEach((photo, index) => {
          data.append(`photo${index}`, values.profile[index]);
        });
        axios
          .post("you_api_for_file_upload", data, {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            },
          })
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }}
    >
      {(formik) => {
        return (
          <>
            <Form>
              <input
                id="file"
                name="profile"
                type="file"
                onChange={(event) => {
                  const files = event.target.files;
                  let myFiles =Array.from(files);
                  formik.setFieldValue("profile", myFiles);
                }}
                multiple
              />
              <ErrorMessage name="profile"/>
              <button type="submit" disabled={formik.isSubmitting}>
                Submit
              </button>
            </Form>
          </>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Note: you can customize min(your choice, "your message")** as per your need.

```
   validationSchema={Yup.object({
        profile:Yup.array().min(1,"select at least 1 file")
      })}
```

Comment: You cannot use input name and setFieldValue as same value, you could use  only if it is of string type. For types other than string the setFieldValue must be of different key

Answer (score 4):

FormIk does not support file uploading and we need to do it in custom way.
Just trigger onChange event and set the file.

If you face any error of **setFieldValue** in TypeScript, then you simply do this:

```
onChange={(event) => {
   if (event.currentTarget.files) {
       formik.setFieldValue(
           "file",
            event.currentTarget.files[0]
        );
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

To handle file in formik with backend all you need to do add the input given below (you can change **avatar** to anything you  want):

```
<input
 type="file"
 name="avatar"
 onChange={(event) => {
 setFieldValue('avatar', event.currentTarget.files[0]);
 }}
 />
```

onSubmit you can access file using values obj like **values.avatar**.

On server-side (express) to access the file we use **req.file**
You also have to use multer that will automatically detect file to handle it on the server-side

Comment: So firstly we need inside `onSubmit`, make a request with mutipart/form-data to upload all files and then second request to create a new entity (and for example, we can receive URL or FileEntity from the first upload request and pass it to the create dto)?

Answer (score 1):

I used simple trick

```
<Field name="image">
{ (form , meta , value ) =>
const {setFieldValue} = form 
return (  
<input name="image" type="file" onChange={(e) => setFieldValue(e.target.file[0])}
)
}
</Field>

for multiple image
<input name="image" type="file" onChange={(e) => setFieldValue(e.target.files)}
or use loop
for( i=0 ; i < e.target.file; i++){
setFieldValue([...image , e.target.file])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle file in formik with backend all you need to do add the input given below (you can change **avatar** to anything you want):

```
<input
 type="file"
 name="avatar"
 onChange={(event) => {
 setFieldValue('avatar', event.currentTarget.files[0]);
 }}
 />
```

onSubmit you can access file using values obj like **values.avatar**.

On server-side (express) to access the file we use **req.file** You also have to use multer & cloudinary that will detect file to handle it on the server-side