# Upload file to Django rest API using Formik in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, formik

Is it possible to upload file (Image) to Django rest api from Reactjs client using Formik ?

Answer (score 0):

Django/DRF allows to upload file quite easly : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/ and for DRF : [Django Rest Framework File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473572/django-rest-framework-file-upload)

As for Formik: [ReactJS: How to handle Image / File upload with Formik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149756/reactjs-how-to-handle-image-file-upload-with-formik)

Comment: Yes but the problem is that i can't send the file using axios

Comment: What do you mean you can't ? You can through almost any known http client.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios for axios e.g. Angular has it's own too.

Comment: yes if you look to the response you will find out that is using formData and not formik

Comment: Did you check this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56161034/10034177, it uses formik with html element to set the file into the attribute of a native element.

Answer (score 0):

```
const formData = new FormData();
const fileInput = document.querySelector('input[name="profile_picture"]');
if (fileInput && fileInput.files && fileInput.files.length > 0) {
  formData.append('profile_picture', fileInput.files[0]);
}
```