# File type input field found empty when come back to the previous step in formik wizard

Tags: reactjs, file, input, formik, wizard

I have created multi-step form using [formik-wizard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik-wizard), I added file type input field in first step but if I go to 2nd step and come back to 1st step then file input field found empty.
How can I solve this issue ?

Here is my [code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-pond-xmqxtn?file=/src/components/BasicInfo/index.jsx) on codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Formik doesn't support file upload by default, but you can try the solution by following the link:

[ReactJS: How to handle Image / File upload with Formik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149756/reactjs-how-to-handle-image-file-upload-with-formik)

You can store the file value in a state variable and use it during form submission.