# Simple way to upload image in next.js and using Formik

Tags: reactjs, next.js, formik

I want to know the way which where the image can be uploaded to my project. First I want to upload one image to internal folder, second, I want to upload multi images to the same folder

this this my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import Router from 'next/router';
import { forwardRef } from 'react';
import { useFormik, Formik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { FiDollarSign } from 'react-icons/fi';
import NavbarPage from '../../components/navBar';
import Footer from '../../components/footer';

const newproduct = () => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession({
    required: true,
  })
    const [token, setToken] = React.useState('')
    React.useEffect(() => {
      if(status === 'unauthenticated') Router.replace("/auth/login");
    }, [status]);
    if(status === 'loading'){
      return <div className='h-screen w-screen flex justify-center items-center'><Spinner color="#f59e0b" className="h-12" /></div>
    }

    if(status === 'authenticated'){
      
    return (
        <div className=" bg-gray-700">
    
    <div className='bg-white'>
        <NavbarPage />
    </div>
        <div className='p-4 dashboardHeight' style={{minHeight: 'calc(100vh-206px)'}}>
        <h1 className='p-6 font-bold text-4xl text-slate-50'>New Product</h1>
        <div className='flex justify-center w-full'>

      
            <Formik
            initialValues= {{
            title: '',
            brand: '',
            category: '',
            price: '',
            quantity: '',
            mImage: '',
            aImages: '',
            }}
            validationSchema= {validateSchema}
            onSubmit={ async(values) => {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(values))
            
        //       const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3030/product", {
        //         method: 'POST',
        //         body: JSON.stringify(values),
        //         headers: { 
        //           "Content-Type": "application/json",
        //           "Authorization": `"${session.user.accessToken}"`
        //       }
        // })

                // const user = await res.json();
            }}
            >
        {props => (
      <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit} className="w-4/5" method='post' encType='multipart/form-data'>
        <Field
          dot={true}
          error={props.touched?.title && props.errors?.title}
          label="Title (Latin)"
          name="title"
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          type="text"
        />
        <Field
          dot={true}
          error={props.touched?.brand && props.errors?.brand}
          label="Brand (Latin)"
          name="brand"
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          type="text"
        />
        <Field
          dot={true}
          error={props.touched?.category && props.errors?.category}
          label="Category (Latin)"
          name="category"
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          type="select"
          >
            <option>-Select Product Category-</option>
            <option value="Supermarket">Supermarket</option>
            <option value="Fashion">Fashion</option>
            <option value="Health & Beauty">Health & Beauty</option>
            <option value="Baby Products">Baby Products</option>
            <option value="Phones & Tablets">Phones & Tablets</option>
            <option value="Home & Office">Home & Office</option>
            <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
            <option value="Computing">Computing</option>
            <option value="Sporting Goods">Sporting Goods</option>
            <option value="Gaming">Gaming</option>
            <option value="Automobile">Automobile</option>
          </Field>
        <Field
          dot={true}
          error={props.touched?.price && props.errors?.price}
          icon={<PriceIcon />}
          label="Price"
          name="price"
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          type="text"
        />
        <Field
          dot={true}
          error={props.touched?.quantity && props.errors?.quantity}
          label="Quantity"
          name="quantity"
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          type="text"
        />
        <Field
          dot={true}
          error={props.touched?.mImage && props.errors?.mImage}
          label="Main Image"
          name="mImage"
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          type="file"
        />
        <Field
          dot={false}
          error={props.touched?.aImages && props.errors?.aImages}
          label="Addtional Images"
          name="aImages"
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          type="file"
          // multiple="multiple"
        />
        <button
          className="mt-8 bg-black active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none text-white rounded px-4 py-1"
          type="submit"
        >
          Add Product
        </button>
      </form>)}
            </Formik>
            </div>
        </div>
        <Footer/>
        </div>
    )
    }
}

export default newproduct

// Yup validation schema
const validateSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    title: Yup.string().required('Field is required'),
    brand: Yup.string().required('Field is required'),
    category: Yup.string().required('Field is required'),
    price: Yup.string().required('Field is required'),
    quantity: Yup.string().required('Field is required'),
    mImage: Yup.string(),
    aImages: Yup.string(),
  });
  
  /*  COMPONENT LOGIC */
  
  const style = {
    dot: `after:content-['*'] after:ml-0.5 after:text-red-500`,
    error: `ring-red-500 ring-1`,
    disabled: `cursor-not-allowed`,
    container: `relative mb-6 mt-3`,
    errorMessage: `text-sm text-red-500 mt-2`,
    checkboxLabel: `block overflow-hidden h-6 rounded-full bg-gray-300`,
    checkboxContainer: `relative w-10 mr-2 align-middle select-none mt-2`,
    iconContainer: `absolute flex border border-transparent left-0 top-0 h-full w-10`,
    icon: `flex items-center justify-center rounded-tl rounded-bl z-10 text-gray-400 text-lg h-full w-full`,
    checkbox: `checked:bg-blue-500 checked:right-0 focus:outline-none right-4 duration-200 ease-in absolute block w-6 h-6 rounded-full bg-white border-4 appearance-none cursor-pointer`,
    default: `text-base relative flex flex-1 w-full mt-1 rounded-md py-2 px-4 bg-white text-gray-700 placeholder-gray-400 text-base focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:border-transparent border`,
  };
  
  const Field = forwardRef(
    (
      { disabled, dot, error, icon, label, name, type = 'text', ...rest },
      ref,
    ) => {
      let component;
  
      // if you won't use select, you can delete this part
      if (type === 'select') {
        component = (
          <select
            aria-required={dot}
            aria-invalid={!!error}
            className={`${style.default} ${disabled ? style.disabled : ''}
               ${error ? style.error : 'border-gray-300'}
            `}
            disabled={disabled}
            id={name}
            name={name}
            ref={ref}
            {...rest}
          />
        );
      }
      // if you won't use textarea, you can delete this part
      if (type === 'textarea') {
        component = (
          <textarea
            aria-required={dot}
            aria-invalid={!!error}
            className={`${style.default} ${disabled ? style.disabled : ''}
               ${error ? style.error : 'border-gray-300'}
            `}
            disabled={disabled}
            id={name}
            name={name}
            ref={ref}
            {...rest}
          />
        );
      }
  
      // if you won't use checkbox, you can delete this part and the classes checkbox, checkboxContainer and checkboxLabel
      if (type === 'checkbox') {
        component = (
          <div className={style.checkboxContainer}>
            <input
              aria-required={dot}
              aria-invalid={!!error}
              className={`${style.checkbox} ${disabled ? style.disabled : ''}`}
              disabled={disabled}
              id={name}
              name={name}
              type="checkbox"
              {...rest}
            />
            <span className={style.checkboxLabel} />
          </div>
        );
      }
  
      // if you won't use input, you can delete this part
      if (type !== 'checkbox' && type !== 'select' && type !== 'textarea') {
        component = (
          <div className="relative">
            <div className={style.iconContainer}>
              <div className={style.icon}>{icon}</div>
            </div>
            <input
              aria-required={dot}
              aria-invalid={!!error}
              className={`${style.default} ${icon ? 'pl-12' : ''}
                 ${error ? style.error : 'border-gray-300'}
                 ${disabled ? style.disabled : ''}
              `}
              disabled={disabled}
              id={name}
              name={name}
              type={type}
              ref={ref}
              {...rest}
            />
            {error && <ErrorIcon />}
          </div>
        );
      }
  
      return (
        <div className={`${style.container} ${disabled ? 'opacity-50' : ''}`}>
          <label htmlFor={name} className={`text-white ${dot && style.dot}`}>
            {label}
          </label>
          {component}
          {error && (
            <span role="alert" className={style.errorMessage}>
              {error}
            </span>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    },
  );
  
  Field.displayName = 'Field';
  
  const ErrorIcon = () => (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="15"
      height="15"
      fill="currentColor"
      className="absolute right-2 -mt-7 text-red-500"
      viewBox="0 0 1792 1792"
    >
      <path d="M1024 1375v-190q0-14-9.5-23.5t-22.5-9.5h-192q-13 0-22.5 9.5t-9.5 23.5v190q0 14 9.5 23.5t22.5 9.5h192q13 0 22.5-9.5t9.5-23.5zm-2-374l18-459q0-12-10-19-13-11-24-11h-220q-11 0-24 11-10 7-10 21l17 457q0 10 10 16.5t24 6.5h185q14 0 23.5-6.5t10.5-16.5zm-14-934l768 1408q35 63-2 126-17 29-46.5 46t-63.5 17h-1536q-34 0-63.5-17t-46.5-46q-37-63-2-126l768-1408q17-31 47-49t65-18 65 18 47 49z" />
    </svg>
  );
  
  const LockIcon = () => (
    <svg
      height="20"
      width="20"
      stroke="currentColor"
      fill="currentColor"
      strokeWidth="0"
      viewBox="0 0 448 512"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path d="M400 224h-24v-72C376 68.2 307.8 0 224 0S72 68.2 72 152v72H48c-26.5 0-48 21.5-48 48v192c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V272c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm-104 0H152v-72c0-39.7 32.3-72 72-72s72 32.3 72 72v72z" />
    </svg>
  );

  const PriceIcon = () => (
    <FiDollarSign className="text-3xl"/>
  );

  const Spinner = ({ color, className }) => (
    <svg
      fill={color}
      viewBox="0 0 1792 1792"
      className={`${className} flex-no-shrink animate-spin`}
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path d="M1760 896q0 176-68.5 336t-184 275.5-275.5 184-336 68.5-336-68.5-275.5-184-184-275.5-68.5-336q0-213 97-398.5t265-305.5 374-151v228q-221 45-366.5 221t-145.5 406q0 130 51 248.5t136.5 204 204 136.5 248.5 51 248.5-51 204-136.5 136.5-204 51-248.5q0-230-145.5-406t-366.5-221v-228q206 31 374 151t265 305.5 97 398.5z" />
    </svg>
  );
```

I tried using FileReader but I didn't get the way and it's hard to handle it with Formik, what is the simplest and best way to implement this

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149756/reactjs-how-to-handle-image-file-upload-with-formik

Answer (score 0):

well, you can upload an image to your project using the File input element in your form and handle the file in your form submission handler.

Here is an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

Add a File input element to your form:

```
<input
  name="mImage"
  type="file"
  onChange={(event) => {
    // handle the file input change event
  }}
/>
```

then, in your form submission handler, get the file from the event.target.files property of the input element:

```
onSubmit={(event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const file = event.target.files[0];
  // do something with the file, such as uploading it to a server
}}
```

To upload multiple images, you can use the multiple attribute of the File input element and handle the files in your form submission handler in a similar way.