# Why use `concat` instead of `push` in this instance?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I was browsing the answers to this question: [Can I dispatch an action in reducer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730793/can-i-dispatch-an-action-in-reducer) and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730793/can-i-dispatch-an-action-in-reducer#answer-41260990), I see the following:

```
actionQueue = actionQueue.concat([asyncAction]);
```

which is essentially the same as:

```
actionQueue.push(asyncAction);
```

(ignoring that the `concat` call is creating a new array and re-assigning it to `actionQueue`, the result is the same -- an array with `asyncAction` appended to it).

Initially, I thought that it (perhaps) performed better (somehow), and someone else was apparently wondering the same as they beat me to it in jsperf: [Array .concat() vs. .push()](https://jsperf.com/array-concat-vs-push-2/17).

As the results of the jsperf testing show, the `concat` method is significantly slower than `push` (at least as far as Chrome is concerned).

Is there something I'm missing?
Is there a reason `concat` would be preferred in this use case?

Comment: I believe it's all to do with `immutability`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If some other code has a reference to the existing array in `actionQueue`, using `concat` will not affect that.

```js
var a1 = [1];
var b1 = a1
a1 = a1.concat([2])

var a2 = [1];
var b2 = a2
a2.push(2)

console.log('b1', b1)
console.log('b2', b2)
```

Comment: even though the new array created by `concat` is being reassigned to the same variable?

Comment: @pete: That's only one variable.  It doesn't affect other references to the array.

Comment: I added a code sample to the answer to help make it clearer. Hopefully @SLaks does not mind me doing it :)

Answer (score 12):

## Push()

The `push()` method is a generic method similar to `call()` or `apply()`. It will mutate your array (or object), pushing a new value into it.

[Push: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

## Concat()

The `concat()` method returns a new array, with the values merged. This also avoids mutation side effects.

[Concat: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 5):

In simple push append the array in the same reference, while concat doestn't effect the orignal array. Check out following snippet

```js
let x = [1,2,3,4];
let y = x.concat(5);
// At this step y hold [1,2,3,4,5] and x remain unchanged to [1,2,3,4]
document.write('x=>'+x);
document.write('y=>'+y);

let z = x.push(5);
// At this step z hold 5 and x is now changed to [1,2,3,4,5]
document.write('x=>'+x);
document.write('z=>'+z);
```