# How to use one single alerts store in Redux when using combineReducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I have the following React modules:

**reducers/index.js**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {connectRouter} from 'connected-react-router';
import Paths from './Paths';
import Messages from './Messages';

const reducerHistory = (history) => combineReducers({
    router: connectRouter(history),
    messages: Messages,
    paths: Paths,
})

export default reducerHistory;
```

**reducers/Messages.js**

```
import {
  SHOW_MESSAGE,
  CLEAR_MESSAGE
} from '../constants/ActionTypes';

const INIT_STATE = {
  showMessage: false,
  alertType: null,
  message: null
}

const Messages = (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CLEAR_MESSAGE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        showMessage: false,
        alertType: null,
        message: null
      }
    }
    case SHOW_MESSAGE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        showMessage: true,
        alertType: action.payload.alertType,
        message: action.payload.message
      }
    }
    default:
      return {
        ...state
      }
  }
}

export default Messages;
```

**reducers/Paths.js**

```
import {
  CONNECT_PATH_SUCCESS,
  CREATE_PATH_SUCCESS,
  PATH_STEP_SUCCESS,
  OPEN_PATH_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_PATHS_SUCCESS,
  UPDATE_PATH_SUCCESS,
  SET_LOADING,
} from '../constants/ActionTypes';

const INIT_STATE = {
  connection: false,
  pathsList: [],
  path: null,
  data: null,
  metadata: null,
  prevStep: null,
  nextStep: null,
  currentStep: null,
  currentColumns: [],
  loading: false,
  breadCrumbs: [],
}

const Paths = (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CONNECT_PATH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        connection: true,
        loading: false
      }
    case CREATE_PATH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
      }
    case OPEN_PATH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload.data.data.entries,
        metadata: action.payload.data.data.meta,
        nextStep: action.payload.data.data.previous_entity,
        prevStep: action.payload.data.data.next_entity,
        currentStep: action.payload.data.data.current_entity,
        currentColumns: action.payload.data.data.entity_columns,
        loading: false
      }
    case PATH_STEP_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload.data.data.entries,
        metadata: action.payload.data.data.meta,
        prevStep: action.payload.data.data.next_entity,
        nextStep: action.payload.data.data.previous_entity,
        currentStep: action.payload.data.data.current_entity,
        currentColumns: action.payload.data.data.entity_columns,
        loading: false
      }
    case FETCH_PATHS_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        pathsList: action.payload.paths.paths.paths_list,
        loading: false
      }
    }
    case UPDATE_PATH_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        metadata: action.payload.metadata.newMetadata,
        loading: false
      }
    }
    case SET_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      }
    default:
      return {
        ...state,
      }
  }
}

export default Paths;
```

I want **Messages.js** reducer to handle error, warning and info alerts of the whole system, so I need other reducers, such as **Paths.js** to dispatch **Message.js** actions in order to set on or off the alerts state. I thought of dispatching **Messages.js** actions from other reducers, but I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730793/can-i-dispatch-an-action-in-reducer#:%7E:text=Dispatching%20an%20action%20within%20a,actions%20and%20other%20side%20effects.) that it shouldn't be done.

So my question is how can I manage alerts information in Redux from a single reducers, instead of having to reply it on every reducer?

Comment: You can call from the client to both messages.js and paths.js, you don't have to call paths.js from messages.js. Each time you want to manage the messages - call it from the client, and so paths. If you need something to be shared, create a new reducer for both actions.

Comment: @OrAssayag That's exactly what I am trying to avoid. Currently I can handle alerts from reducers but I have to reply such management on each reducer, but such redundancy occurs only because I haven't found a way to use a single reducer for all stores. What you propose to dispatch both actions from clients would be the oposite of what I pursue, because that way each component would need to handle alerts logic while, by giving it to reducers, components only have to check for alerts to display or not.

Comment: @OrAssayag I can't grasp you proposal of "create a new reducer for both actions", if you share and example or a model code as an answer and it works, you'll collect the points awarded.