# How to count the time an element has focus in redux react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react component and I want to perform an action if it has focus for 2 seconds. In pure react I had internal state where I could handle this.
What is the approperate way to do it using Redux?

Comment: Sounds like you need something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout/35415559

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use React for ephemeral state that doesn't matter to the app globally
>   and doesn't mutate in complex ways. For example, a toggle in some UI
>   element, a form input state. Use Redux for state that matters globally
>   or is mutated in complex ways. For example, cached users, or a post
>   draft.
>
> Sometimes you'll want to move from Redux state to React state (when
>   storing something in Redux gets awkward) or the other way around (when
>   more components need to have access to some state that used to be
>   local).
>
> The rule of thumb is: do whatever is less awkward.

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287

This is the answer by [Dan Abramov](https://github.com/gaearon) creator of Redux.

In your case, I think it's OK to use React component state.