# Making a post call to login user using React Redux

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I have created a login form where i accept the user email and password.

I want to make api call to api server to validate the credentials against database how can i make a ajax request . I have heard of Redux can that be used for making ajax request.

```
class LoginComponent extends React.Component{

 constructor(){
  super()
 }

 handleEmailChange(e){
  //... email validation stuff
 }

 handlePasswordChange(e){
  //...
 }

 handleSubmit(e){
  //..login logic goes here
 }

}
```

Comment: redux is not fro making ajax request.You can make normal XML HTTP request and update store

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to configure the `redux-thunk` middleware to support asynchronous actions. Then, you'll want to pick an asynchronous library to handle actual http requests. [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) and [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) are popular ones.

The redux documentation has a great [async action example](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#async-action-creators) of how to get started with your exact request

You'll also find some very helpful information in another [related post by Dan Abramov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout/35415559#35415559), the creator of `redux`.