# Confused about an auth0 lock example using react and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, auth0

I'm looking through the auth0 sample project for using react, redux and auth0 for a login scenario [here](https://auth0.com/blog/secure-your-react-and-redux-app-with-jwt-authentication/).  However I'm a bit confused about this particular example where we call `this.props.doAuthentication()`

```
// App.js
import { loginUser, fetchQuote, doAuthentication, fetchSecretQuote } from '../actions'

// add a constructor
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.props.doAuthentication()
  }
```

Here is the action definition

```
// actions.js

...

const lock = new Auth0Lock('YOUR_CLIENT_ID', 'YOUR_CLIENT_DOMAIN');

export function login() {
  // display lock widget
  return dispatch => {
    lock.show();
  }
}

// Listen to authenticated event and get the profile of the user
export function doAuthentication() {
    return dispatch => {
      lock.on("authenticated", function(authResult) {
            lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, function(error, profile) {

              if (error) {
                // handle error
                return dispatch(lockError(error))
              }

              localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile))
              localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken)
              return dispatch(lockSuccess(profile))
            });
      });
    }
}

...
```

I'm new to redux so maybe this is an obvious answer but

1. Where is doAuthentication bound to the the props in App.js?  Assuming that App.js is the top level root app component.
2. Doesn't doAuthentication generate a function that expects a dispatch argument?  Why don't we do anything in the constructor with the returned function from doAuthentication()? If we don't assign the returned function to anything, does `this.props.doAuthentication` persist anything or have any effects?  Shouldn't it be something like `doAuthentication()(someDispatchFunction)`  Where does this dispatch function come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*1.Where is doAuthentication bound to the the props in App.js? Assuming that App.js is the top level root app component.*

**Ans:**
The action `doAuthentication` is bound with the `props` of `App` component using the middleware called [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk).

```
let createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, api)(createStore)

let store = createStoreWithMiddleware(quotesApp)
```

The above two line of code would have done it for your. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout/35415559#35415559) why `redux-thunk` is required.

*2.Doesn't doAuthentication generate a function that expects a dispatch argument? Why don't we do anything in the constructor with the returned function from doAuthentication()? If we don't assign the returned function to anything, does this.props.doAuthentication persist anything or have any effects? Shouldn't it be something like doAuthentication()(someDispatchFunction) Where does this dispatch function come from?*

**Ans:** 
2.1 Yes, the function which is returned by `doAuthentication` function expects a `dispatch` method as to be a first parameter.

2.2, 2.3 Here the `doAuthentication` action creator's job is to create a `Redux action` which would just listen for the event called `authenticated`. When we call doAuthentication action creator, it returns a `Redux action` function which accepts a `dispatch` method as first parameter and `getState` method as second. The parameters would be passed by the `redux-thunnk` middleware.

The `redux-thunk` middleware would call the redux action which is return from the `doAuthentication` call since it is `connet`-ed. Otherwise we have to dispatch the action returned by the `doAuthentication` as like the below,

```
this.props.dispatch(doAuthentication())
```

2.4 We can do as you mention `doAuthentication()(someDispatchFunction)`, but consider this quote

> If Redux Thunk middleware is enabled, any time you attempt to
>   dispatch a function instead of an action object, the middleware will
>   call that function with dispatch method itself as the first argument.

And, you can find a detailed info about the `redux-thunk` with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35415559/744534)