# In React Redux How to execute two or more actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In React-redux project, sometimes we need to execute two actions.

For example,

```
// I have to both 
handleAddItem(){
  this.props.actions.addItem(); // working
  this.props.actions.updateItemList(); // not working
}
```

Above code is not working. It just seems to be executed first action `addItem()`. `updateItemList()` is not working.

But I found hack to execute both actions,

```
handleAddItem(){
  this.props.actions.addItem(); // working
  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.props.actions.updateItemList(); // It's working
  }, 1000);
}
```

Is there accurate code to execute 2 more actions?

Comment: Have you tried dispatching those actions?

Comment: Does updateItemList() rely on addItem()?  If it does, you need to make it a callback to addItem or have addItem return a promise.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using two actions at a time? It's generally better to update your state with a single action.

Comment: Do the actions have asynchronous calls?

Comment: @Bezzi I can't understand exactly dispatching.

Comment: @DavidL.Walsh It just sample functions. In my case, execute addItem() and updateItemList() is to change list order.

Comment: @Max Sindwani Yes. both are asynchronous functions.

Comment: @jmargolisvt thanks. I'll find 'promise'

Comment: You may also want to consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout/35415559#35415559 - tldr you can define an action that returns a function to dispatch multiple functions.

Comment: @MaxSindwani Thanks :) then. How can define sync actions?

Answer (score 1):

To add to my comment earlier, [How to dispatch a Redux action with a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout/35415559#35415559) explains a widely used solution to your problem. As for differentiating between sync and async actions, simply return either an object (synchronous support) or a function (asynchronous support).