# What is the difference between using redux-thunk and calling dispatch() directly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm in the learning phase of understanding redux state management and still trying to negotiate the bewildering jungle of boilerplate code and middleware, much of which I'm taking on faith as 'good medicine'. So I hope you'll bear with me on this perhaps rudimentary question.

I know that `redux-thunk` allows action creators to proceed asynchronously and dispatch a regular action at a subsequent time. For example, I can define a thunk action creator in my `actions.js`:

```
export function startTracking() {
  return (dispatch => {
     someAsyncFunction().then(result => dispatch({
       type: types.SET_TRACKING,
       location: result
     }))
  })
}
```

And invoke it from within a React component like so:

```
onPress={() => this.props.dispatch(actions.startTracking())}
```

**My question is**, what advantage does the above code confer over simply dispatching an action from inside an asynchronous callback?

```
import { store } from '../setupRedux'
...

export function startTracking() {
 someAsyncFunction().then(result => {
   store.dispatch({
     type: types.SET_TRACKING,
     location: result
   })
 })
}
```

which I would invoke inside my component

```
onPress={() => actions.startTracking()}
```

or even

```
onPress={actions.startTracking}
```

Is there anything problematic with accessing `store` directly via an import as I'm doing in the 2nd example?

Comment: check this answer by redux creator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing wrong doing so. From the [redux-thunk page](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#why-do-i-need-this):

> If you’re not sure whether you need it, you probably don’t.

The creator of redux explain the advantage of using it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout/35415559#35415559):

> This looks simpler but we don’t recommend this approach. The main reason we dislike it is because it forces store to be a singleton. This makes it very hard to implement server rendering. On the server, you will want each request to have its own store, so that different users get different preloaded data.

Basically, using redux-thunk will save you the store import in each action creator file and you will be able to have multiple store. This approach also give you the opportunity to write a little bit less code and to avoid spaghetti code. Many redux developer don't like to import the store and to manually dispatch because it can create circular dependencies if the code is badly separated (importing an action name from the action creator file in the reducers file and importing the store from the reducers file in the action creator file). Also, dispatching directly an action like that might break the middleware workflow, ie: the action might not be handled by a middleware.

But honestly, if you don't see an advantage to it yet, don't use it. If one day you have trouble with async actions, redux-thunk might be the answer.

Comment: Thanks. That explanation from Dan Abramov (which was also suggested in the other comment) makes things clearer, in particular the point about a singleton store. Pity that it is attached to a question with a somewhat unrelated title.