# Use of boilerplate actions and reducers in redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, frontend

I have been following the widely given advice of learning React development by first mastering component `props`, encapsulating UI state in component level `this.state` and passing it down selectively through the component tree. It's been an enlightening experience. I've come to appreciate the power of the stateless view design pattern and I feel that I've been able to achieve robust and well organized results using these techniques.

Moving on, I am now trying to incorporate more sophisticated state management using `redux`. But as I wade through the complexity and integrate `redux` into my apps,  I find myself confronting the following observations about how my code has evolved. Some of these developments seem sensible, but others make me question whether I'm doing things 'right'.

**1) Action Creators as the nexus of business and UI logic**

I find that much of the logic that was previously implemented in the React lifecycle functions `componentDidUpdate` etc., and in `onTouch/onPress` handlers, is now implemented in *action creators*. This seems to be a positive development as it keeps 'everything in the same place' and allows for unit testing.

**Question**: Is it best practice to concentrate business logic in a web of fairly intricate action creators?

**2) Hollowed out `reducers`**

As a corollary to #1 above, I find that my `reducers` and their corresponding `action` objects have evolved into a de-facto list of setters that do little more than update the state store with the passed along values, in this fashion:

```
case types.SAVE_ORDER: 
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    order: action.order,
  });
```

A big part of the reason for this is that `reducers` are supposed to be *pure functions* and therefore I'm limited in what I can do with them (e.g. no async processing). Additionally, reducers are allowed only to operate on their respective sub-section of the store state. Given that much of my app's complexity already necessarily resides in the *action creators*, I find it hard to justify arbitrarily migrating complexity into `reducers` simply for the sake of making them 'look useful'.

**Question**: Is it normal, and acceptable practice to have boilerplate `reducers` that function merely as glorified setters to the redux store state?

**3) `redux-thunk` everywhere**

I've asked separately on SO why `redux-thunk` is even necessary (as opposed to calling standard action creators inside of async callbacks/utility functions). I've been pointed to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35415559/1628461) by Dan Abramov which provides a very satisfactory explanation (vis-a-vis scalability, server side rendering and myraid other reasons).

Having accepted the necessity of `redux-thunk`, I find that the majority of my *action creators* need to perform async actions, need access to `getState`, or `dispatch` multiple changes to the state. As a result I've been returning '`thunks`' extensively.

**Question:** Is it normal for a redux application to rely extensively on `thunk`'ed action creators, and rarely to fire a standard object action directly?

**4) Redux as global `this.state`**

In the final analysis, it seems my app's `redux` store has evolved to effectively resemble a global `this.state`. You could think of it as keeping the entire application state in `this.state` in the outermost container component, but without the inevitable mess that comes with passing the said `state` down through nested layers of `props`, and any changes back up the component tree through a rats-nest of *handler* functions.

**Question:** Is *redux* the correct tool to use for a global state store? Are there alternatives out there that behave more akin to *react*'s built-in `this.state`, allowing a global application state to be propagated through stateless react components, and updated from throughout the application via a centralized 'switchboard', without the seemingly endless web of boilerplate, constants and `switch` statements that come with adopting *redux*?

**5) One single action type?**
This follow up question is inspired by one of the posted comments.

**Question**: Could one legitimately (in all seriousness, not just blatantly demonstrating a point) use redux with precisely one action type?

Example - Action creator:

```
export function someActionCreator(various_params){
  return (dispatch, getState => {
    // ... business logic here ....
    asyncIfThisIfThat().then(val => {
      dispatch({
        // type: 'UPDATE_STATE', // Don't even bother setting a type 
        order: val
      })
    })
  )
}
```

The one universal reducer case:

```
export default function app(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  return Object.assign({}, state, action)
  // Just unconditionally merge into state!
}
```

Seems to me this would provide a globally scoped state object that is automatically mapped to `connect`ed components, and one that benefits from all the advantages of immutable state and interoperable with React `props`. In this scheme, **`dispatch` effectively becomes a global `setState`**.

---

Note - Please don't take this question wrong - this is certainly not criticism of *redux*. As a learner I am obviously in no position to judge a technology backed by the expertise of thousands and the support of millions. I have no doubt of its value in the right context.

I'm just sensing the smell of a questionable pattern in my own code and wondering what, if anything I'm doing wrong, or whether I'm using the right tool for the task.

Comment: you don't *need* boilerplate for redux. you can have a single action with a single reducer and it will still work. how much boilerplate you add is completely up to you, and how verbose you want to be. @markerikson has a redux blog and a huge list of resources that answer all your other questions https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer is mostly speaking from my own experience learning redux and using it professionally. The team I was on went down the same path of setter-like actions, and then shifted away to action names that were more event-based and describe what had happened rather than what should happen.

> Question: Is it best practice to concentrate business logic in a web of fairly intricate action creators?

This depends on how your actions are named. In your case, your actions are very glorified setters, so all of your business logic is going to live inside of Action Creators. If you name your actions to be more event-like (descriptive about *what happened*) rather than setters, you're going to have some of the business logic shift into the reducers, and complexity removed from action creators, because event actions naturally feel more re-usable across different reducers. When you do setter actions, the tendency is to have setter-actions that interact with only 1 reducer, and create more setter-actions when you want other reducers to be involved.

If you have an app for a school, and a student is expelled, you'll likely dispatch a `REMOVE_STUDENT` and then a`DELETE_GRADES_FOR_STUDENT` action. If your action has an event-like name, you may be more inclined to just have a `STUDENT_EXPELLED` action that the grades reducer and student roster reducer both act upon it.

There is nothing technically stopping you from having setter-like names, and acting on them in multiple reducers, though. It's just not the tendency that my team fell into when working in Redux and using setter-like names. We didn't want to muddy up the expectations and purity that came from having concise action names, where the impact on state was very clear. `REMOVE_STUDENT_GRADES` and `DELETE_STUDENT_FROM_ROSTER` felt good.

> Question: Is it normal, and acceptable practice to have boilerplate reducers that function merely as glorified setters to the redux store state?

It is normal, but not necessarily correct. This is how our codebase grew initially - we even had standards to name our actions as `RESET_...`, `SET_...`, `REMOVE_...`, `ADD_...`, `UPDATE...` etc. This seemed to work for a while, until we bumped into cases where we needed multiple reducers to update according to a single action.

You actions will evolve in one of these 2 ways (or both)

1. Dispatch multiple actions in a row (**you must** use a library like [**redux-batch-actions**](https://github.com/tshelburne/redux-batched-actions) if you want to dispatch multiple actions in a row). We chose not to use this, because it's cumbersome and didn't feel like it scaled very well as our codebase grew in size.
2. Rename your actions to be more generic and re-usable across different reducers. This is what we ended up doing. Having actions as setters and getters was cumbersome. Dan Abramov and others has expressed their opinion that Redux Actions should be `events` (a description of a thing that has happened), rather than `instructions` (a description of a thing that should happen). The team I work on agreed with this, and we've moved away from the setters-style of actions. There was much debate about this earlier on when Redux was new.

**In scenario 1**, you might do something like this:

```
// student has been expelled from school, remove all of their data
store.dispatch(batchActions(
    removeStudentFromClass(student),
    removeStudentsGrades(student)
));

// student roster reducer
case REMOVE_STUDENT_FROM_CALLS:
    /* ... */

// student grades reducer
case REMOVE_STUDENT_GRADES:
    /* ... */
```

If you go down this path without using Batch Actions, it's an absolute nightmare. Each dispatched event will recompute state, and re-render your app. This falls apart very quickly.

```
// student has been expelled from school, remove all of their data
store.dispatch(removeStudentFromClass(student));
// app re-rendered, students grades exist, but no student!
store.dispatch(removeStudentsGrades(student));
```

In the above code, you dispatch an action to remove the student from class, and then the app re-renders. If you have a grades page open, and you can see the students grades, but the student is removed, you're very likely going to reference state in the student roster reducer to grab the student info and that can/will throw a JS error. Bad news. You have the grades for a student of `undefined`?! I ran into issues like this myself, and it was part of our motivation for moving to option 2 below. You'll hear about these kinds of states called "intermediate states" and they're problematic.

**In scenario 2** your code might look more like this:

```
store.dispatch(expelStudent(student));

// student roster reducer
case EXPEL_STUDENT:
    /* ... */

// student grades reducer
case EXPEL_STUDENT:
    /* ... */
```

With the code above, the student is expelled via the action, and their data is removed from all reducers in 1 step. This scales nicely and your codebase reflects the business terms related to your app that you would talk about day-to-day. You can also perform the same state updates for multiple events if it makes sense from a business logic perspective:

```
case EXPEL_STUDENT:
case STUDENT_DROPPED_OUT:
case STUDENT_TRANSFERRED:
    /* remove student info, all actions must have action.payload.student */
```

> Question: Is it normal for a redux application to rely extensively on thunk'ed action creators, and rarely to fire a standard object action directly?

Yes definitely. As soon as you need to grab a little piece of data from the store in an action creator, it has to become a thunk. Thunks are very common, and should have been part of the redux library.

As our thunks grew in complexity, they got confusing and difficult to easily understand. We started to abuse promises and return values and it was taxing. Testing them was also a nightmare. You have to mock out everything, it's painful.

To solve this problem, we pulled in [**redux-saga**](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga). Redux-saga is easily testable with libraries like [**redux-saga-test-plan**](https://github.com/jfairbank/redux-saga-test-plan) or [**redux-saga-test-engine**](https://github.com/timbuckley/redux-saga-test-engine) (we use test-engine and have contributed to it as needed).

We aren't 100% sagas, and don't aim to be. We still use thunks as needed. If you need to upgrade your action to be a little smarter, and the code is very simple, there's no reason why you shouldn't upgrade that action to a thunk.

As soon as an action creator gets complex enough to warrant some unit testing, redux-saga might come in handy.

Redux-saga does have a rough learning curve to it, and feels quite bizarre at first. Testing sagas manually is miserable. Great learning experience, but I would not ever do it again.

> Question: Is redux the correct tool to use for a global state store? Are there alternatives out there that behave more akin to react's built-in this.state, allowing a global application state to be propagated through stateless react components, and updated from throughout the application via a centralized 'switchboard', without the seemingly endless web of boilerplate, constants and switch statements that come with adopting redux?

[**MobX**](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) - I've heard good things about it from people who have your same complaints about Redux (too much boilerplate, too many files, everything is disconnected) I don't use it myself and have not used it, though. There's a good chance that you'll enjoy it more than Redux. It solves the same problem, so if you actually enjoy it more then it may be worth the switch. Developer experience is very important if you're going to work on code for a long time.

I'm okay with the Redux boilerplate and whatnot. The team I worked on has made macros to scaffold out the boilerplate of creating new actions, and we have lots of tests in place so our Redux code is pretty solid. Once you work with it for a while, you internalize the boilerplate and it's not as exhausting.

If you do stick with Redux long term, and are savvy enough to adopt [**flow on top of redux**](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/redux/) it's a huge win for long-term maintainability. Fully-typed redux code is amazing to work in, especially for refactoring. It's so easy to refactor a reducer/actionCreators, but forget to update unit test code. If your unit tests are covered by flow, it's going to complain that you're calling a function incorrectly immediately. It's wonderful.

Introducing Flow is a complex hurdle to get over, but well worth it. I wasn't involved in the initial set up, and I assume it's gotten easier to introduce to a codebase, but I'd imagine that it will take some learning and hours. Worth it though. Definitely 100% worth it.

> Question: Could one legitimately (in all seriousness, not just blatantly demonstrating a point) use redux with precisely one reducer?

You definitely could, it could work for a small app. It wouldn't scale well for a larger team, and refactoring seems like it would become a nightmare. Splitting the store up into separate reducers lets you isolate responsibilities and concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and well written account. I see a lot of similarity between your experience and what I'm discovering right now. It's going to take some time to digest but mobX sounds more like what I had in mind when I sought out redux after hitting the limitations of component level `setState`. Too late for our current project but I'll be sure to read up on it.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a Redux maintainer.  I'll give you some initial answers and point you to some learning resources, and I can answer further questions as needed.

First, Cory Danielson has given some *excellent* advice, and I want to echo pretty much everything he said.

**Action creators, reducers, and business logic**:

I'll quote [the Redux FAQ entry on splitting business logic between action creators and reducers](https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/CodeStructure.html#structure-business-logic):

> There's no single clear answer to exactly what pieces of logic should go in a reducer or an action creator. Some developers prefer to have “fat” action creators, with “thin” reducers that simply take the data in an action and blindly merge it into the corresponding state. Others try to emphasize keeping actions as small as possible, and minimize the usage of getState() in an action creator. (For purposes of this question, other async approaches such as sagas and observables fall in the "action creator" category.)
>
> There are some potential benefits from putting more logic into your reducers. It's likely that the action types would be more semantic and more meaningful (such as "USER_UPDATED" instead of "SET_STATE"). In addition, having more logic in reducers means that more functionality will be affected by time travel debugging.
>
> This comment sums up the dichotomy nicely:
>
> > Now, the problem is what to put in the action creator and what in the reducer, the choice between fat and thin action objects. If you put all the logic in the action creator, you end up with fat action objects that basically declare the updates to the state. Reducers become pure, dumb, add-this, remove that, update these functions. They will be easy to compose. But not much of your business logic will be there. If you put more logic in the reducer, you end up with nice, thin action objects, most of your data logic in one place, but your reducers are harder to compose since you might need info from other branches. You end up with large reducers or reducers that take additional arguments from higher up in the state.

I talked about this topic some more in my post [The Tao of Redux, Part 2 - Practice and Philosophy](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-2/) earlier this year (specifically the sections on [action semantics](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-2/#action-semantics) and [thick vs thin reducers](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-2/#thick-and-thin-reducers), and again in [a recent Reddit comment thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/7j42ov/a_homemade_spotify_web_client_made_with_react/dr53shh/?context=3).

**Use of thunks:**

Yes, thunks are a valuable tool for any complex synchronous logic that needs to live outside a component, including any code that needs access to the current store state.  They're also useful for simple async logic (like basic AJAX calls with just success/failure handlers).  I discussed the pros and cons of thunks in my post [Idiomatic Redux: Thoughts on Thunks, Sagas, Abstraction, and Reusability](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/idiomatic-redux-thoughts-on-thunks-sagas-abstraction-and-reusability/).

In my own app, I use thunks in many places, as well as sagas for more complex async logic and workflows, and highly recommend thunks as a useful tool overall.

**Redux as a global store**

I've frequently said that you can use as much or as little abstraction on top of Redux as you want. [You don't *have* to use switch statements](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-2/#switch-statements), you can use lookup tables or any other conditional logic in your reducers, and you are [highly encouraged to reuse reducer logic](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ReusingReducerLogic.html).  In fact, there's [dozens of existing utilities to generate reusable action creators and reducers](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/action-reducer-generators.md), as well as many higher-level abstraction libraries written on top of Redux.

**Use of a single blind-setter reducer**

This is [another topic I looked at in The Tao of Redux, Part 2](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-2/#cursors-and-all-in-one-reducers), and [someone else had a good comment another recent Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/7i4t14/keducer_automate_writing_redux_reducers_with_5/dqwk31l/).  It's certainly technically feasible to do so, but per that Reddit comment, your reducers don't actually "own" the state shape any more.  Instead, the action creators do, and there's nothing stopping them from feeding in data that doesn't make sense for a given action type or reducer.

As I talked about in [The Tao of Redux, Part 1 - Implementation and Intent](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-1/#action-history-should-have-semantic-meaning), one of the key intents behind the creation of Redux was that you should be able to look at a log of dispatched actions and understand where/when/why/how your state was updated.  While Redux itself doesn't care what the `action.type` field actually contains, an action history log will make more sense to you (or some other developer) if the dispatched actions are meaningfully named.  Seeing 10 `"SET_STATE"` actions in a row tells you nothing useful about what's going on, and while you *could* look at the contents of each action and the resulting diff, an action type like `"EXPEL_STUDENT"` means a lot more just by reading it.  In addition, unique action types can also be traced to where they're used in specific places in the codebase, thus helping you isolate where the data is coming from.

Hopefully that helps answer some of your questions.  If you'd like to discuss things further, I usually hang out in the [Reactiflux chat channels on Discord](https://www.reactiflux.com) evenings US time.  Be happy to have you drop by and chat sometime!

Comment: Thanks, and I do appreciate your taking the time to share your thoughts. I did see the FAQ entry on thin/fat reducers, but at the time I didn't know what to make of it. (the fault of unopinionated advice!). Unfortunately many of the 'TodoList' type examples out there don't do a very forceful job of marketing the value of `redux`. I'll be sure to study your blog carefully. I'm intrigued by what you call the 'blind-setter' approach and I'm going to experiment with dispatching cosmetic `type`s that provide a log trail without actual side effects. This could meet my short-term needs nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Try using my lib [redux-light](https://github.com/Gentlee/redux-light). You'll need to use **store.setState** and **store.getState**
similar to **React.Component.setState** without reducers at all, and without other boilerplate.