# Is it OK for a reducer to listen to other actions?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

At the moment I'm creating actions and then a reducer to handle different parts of my app... the different domains.

My app lists classes and pupils.

Currently I have an action that the app has loaded so that I know when to remove the loading spinner, I have actions for classes and pupils. My problem is that I find I need to execute several actions in a row and am not sure if this is a valid way to use redux.

Here is an example function that dispatches several actions after the data is loaded:

```
/**
  * Callback used by readAppData.
  *
  * @param object ioResult An object: {success: boolean, errorObj?: object, data?: string}
  */
  dataLoaded(ioResult: Object) {
    if (ioResult.success === true) {
      this.props.dispatch(appActions.appHasLoaded());
      if (ioResult.data !== '') {
        const jsonData = JSON.parse(ioResult.data);
        this.props.dispatch(classActions.replaceClasses(jsonData.classes));
        this.props.dispatch(pupilActions.replacePupils(jsonData.pupils));
      }

    } else if (ioResult.errorObj.code === 'ENOENT') { // File doesn't exist.
      writeAppData('', this.dataSaved);
    } else { // Some other error.
      this.props.dispatch(appActions.appHasErrored());
    }
  }
```

I was thinking about putting the jsonData.classes and jsonData.pupils into the appActions.appHasLoaded() call and just have a new case for APP_HAS_LOADED in my classes and pupils reducers.

Is this a better approach? To reduce it down to one action? Having separate actions makes it easy to see what is happening... maybe in 6 months time I will have to look through my code to work out exactly what happens on APP_HAS_LOADED if I use it in other reducers. Also the data that is loaded on app start is going to expand beyond just classes and pupils so if I don't combine the calls there could soon be many more dispatches to make - maybe I can store the data in separate files and load each one one at a time which would also fix my problem of having to call mutiple actions in a row.

Is it OK to call dispatch multiple times?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to dispatch multiple actions or have multiple reducers listen to the same action. There are a lot of things to consider in how you design your Redux store, but I found this post to be very helpful in making my decisions for a given situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47803107/use-of-boilerplate-actions-and-reducers-in-redux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.

From Redux creator Dan Abramov:

> Many reducers may handle one action. One reducer may handle many actions.

Referenced in [Redux Docs](https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Actions.html#is-there-always-a-one-to-one-mapping-between-reducers-and-actions)

also, there is a conversation [on github](https://github.com/pitzcarraldo/reduxible/issues/8) about this.

Comment: Thanks for your help... I think the github issue is exactly mine: all examples of actions/reducers that I have seen made me think they were one-to-one