# one action updates multiple reducers performance issue

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers, redux-actions

In the current app I have set up multiple redux reducers to store data. Lets just call them 'user-reducers' and 'pet-reducers'. The 2 are very similar, they both have a posts[]. Now whenever user likes a post inside posts[], an action 'likeDone' is fired. Now I have 2 choices of implementing the redux update:

Option 1: both 'user-reducers' and 'pet-reducers' listens to 'likeDone'. IMO, this is inefficient in the later stages when I have more similar reducers and all of them listing to one action.

Option 2: change 'likeDone' into 2 more explicit actions ex. 'likeUserPostDone' 'likePetPostDone' and each reducer reacts to the matched action. This way, reducer updates seem more efficient but there will be more action types later on which will end up with lots of 'switch - case' and I'm not sure if that is a good practice.

Thanks for reading and please tell me what's the best for my case.

Comment: any reducer shouldn't affect other one based on Action types. define different action types for others.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar Okay thanks, so option 2 that is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48052571/is-it-ok-for-a-reducer-to-listen-to-other-actions is this helpful?

Comment: Hm the topic @OzanBulut sent seems to contradict with your comment. Could you clarify more on why it should be like you said?

Comment: @VahidAkhtar  ??? reducers should not have side effects, (&& affect each other), they should ONLY return state.  Reducers only change based on action types.  When FETCH_SUCCESS, I modify my waitForData reducer and my data reducer.  My UI hides the spinner and shows the data.  WHEN FETCH_FAIL, I hide the spinner and show error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have both reducers listen to your action if they both change when that action occurs.  All redux reducers efficiently listen to all dispatched actions.  They ignore actions if it doesn't change state.

```
const petPostReducer = (prev = defaultValue, action = {}) => {
  const { type, payload} = action;
  switch (type) {
    case "LIKE_DONE": {
      const {id} = payload || {};
      const oldItem = prev[id] || {}
      const newItem = {...oldItem, like: true}
      return {
        ...prev
        [id]: {...updateItem, [id]: newItem};
    }
    default: {
      return prev; // Ignore all other actions != LIKE_DONE
    }
  }
};
```

It is fine to create more explicit actions, but you usually want to do so when you have different actions.  (There are always exceptions)

When possible, avoid logic in your reducers.

If pets and user data are very similar, consider changing your state shape and use one reducer posts.

```
console.log(state.posts) =>
{
   0: {type: 'user' like: false},
   1: {type: 'pet' like: false},
   2: {type: 'user' like: true},
}
```

Please avoid [premature optimization](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/). I often do things that are less efficient in favor of simple, concise, immutable, readable and useful code. If you are targeting a feature phone or find a real performance bottleneck, you will need to measure with performance monitoring tools. The JavaScript engine optimizations are continuously improving and results are often surprising.