# Asynchronous behaviour in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I was working on creating the react-redux application. **But stuck on the point why we shouldn't call the async function (for API calling) in the component method like componentWillMount etc?** Why I've to use the middleware like redux-thunk & saga? Why we cannot call the API request from the action and based on that result, we call the reducer? Is it the bad idea? I didn't understand deeply about this. Can you please help me out to understand the concept of API calling in redux?

Comment: call async API in in redux without using redux-thunk/saga.You . will get warning / error in console.It help u.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN, Thanks for your help and I really appreciate your input. But I think this is not the proper clarification of the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dispatch a Redux action with a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout/35415559#35415559

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see it, you can call async functions anywhere, including in componentWillMount. What a middleware like redux-thunk does, is to add IDs in the dispatched actions, 'ordering' them, avoiding race conditions such as the one that is described in [Writing Async Code in redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout/35415559#35415559)