# How do you update a state with a time interval using redux toolkits?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have the following initial state and slice objects. How do I add values to the hand array every second using dispatch? My intention is to have each dispatch be completed before the next one. I looked at createAsyncThunk but I wasn't clear on how to implement it on the same action repeatedly with a time interval.

```
const initialState = { 
    hand: [],
};

export const stateSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'black',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        updateHand: (state, action) => {
            state.hand = [...state.hand, action.payload]
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this answer your question? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout?rq=1)

Comment: @DaniloCadeddu Yes I looked at that and tried the code below but it never executed the second dispatch inside the setTimeout function.

`dispatch(updateHand([ ...stateSelector.hand, card1 ]))
        setTimeout(()=> {
            updateHand([ ...stateSelector.hand, card2 ])
        }, 1000)`

I am assuming I need some async redux thunk but not sure how to implement it for my case because the second dispatch depends on the result of the first dispatch.