# Function parameter explanation in Redux where a function returns a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I do understand Redux a bit, but I don't understand how you can put a function inside a function.

```
import api from '../utils/api';

import {
  GET_PROFILE, PROFILE_ERROR
} from './types';

export const getCurrentProfile = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await api.get('/profile/me');

    dispatch({
      type: GET_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

I am having issues with this line:

```
export const getCurrentProfile = () => **async (dispatch) => {}**
```

1. Are we defining our own function here with `async (dispatch) => {}`?
2. Why will we define our own function?
3. I know what `dispatch` does, but where do we get it and why are we using it on the two objects?
4. What is the name of this pattern, if any?

Comment: For the name, it's usually called a [curried function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36314/1218980).

Comment: For the why of this pattern within Redux, it's mostly to [enable async redux action function, which is called redux thunks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411423/1218980).

Comment: @EmileBergeron thanks man you're awesome.!!! I need this in both Node.js and React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes. The `getCurrentProfile` returns a new function that takes one parameter.
2. Maybe they will use the function in a closure.  Closures can be used to hide information.
3. Whatever is using the function you create will give the `dispatch` to the function when it calls it.

Comment: Thanks so much @Alex. You're right of course and it solved my issue!

Comment: @RidwanBinMonjur your welcome. mark my answer as correct please :)