# The proper place to change state in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

As [the doc](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html) says:

> Things you should never do inside a reducer:
>
> - Mutate its arguments;
> - Perform side effects like API calls and routing transitions;
> - Call non-pure functions, e.g. Date.now() or Math.random().

If I follow the principle, there are some questions about the code orgnization (my app is a file manager).

For example,

default reducer like this:

```
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  const { path } = action
  if (typeof path === 'undefined') {
    return state
  }

  const ret = {
    ...state,
    [path]: parentNode(state[path], action)
  };

  switch (action.type) {
    case OPEN_NODE:
    case GO_PATH:
      ret['currentPath'] = path
      break
    default:
      break
  }

  return ret
}
```

data struct in `state[path]` likes:

```
{
    'open': false,
    'path': '/tmp/some_folder',
    'childNodes' : [ {'path':'/some/path', 'mode': '0755', 'isfolder': true}, ....],
    'updateTime': Date.now()
}
```

---

Now I need several actions such as `ADD_CHILD`, `DELETE_CHILD` , `RENAME_CHILD`, `MOVE_CHILD`, there are two sulotions(by change state in actions or reducers):

### 1. All functional code in actions:

actions:

```
export function updateChildNodes(path, nodes) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_CHILD_NODES,
    path: path,
    loading: false,
    loaded: true,
    childNodes: nodes,
  };
}

export function addChild(path, node) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState().tree[path]
    var childNodes  = state.childNodes ? state.childNodes :[]
    childNodes.push(node)
    return dispatch(updateChildNodes(path, childNodes))
  }
}

export function deleteChild(parent_path, child_node) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState().tree[parent_path]
    var childNodes = state && state.childNodes ? state.childNodes : []
    for (var i=0; i <=childNodes.length; i++){
      if (childNodes[i].path == child_node.path){
        childNodes.splice(i, 1)
        return dispatch(updateChildNodes(parent_path, childNodes))
      }
    }
  }
}

export function deleteNode(node) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // ajax call
    return api.deleteChild(node.path, () => {
      dispatch(deleteChild(node.parent, node))
    })
  }
}

.....
```

parentNode reducer:

```
function parentNode(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_CHILD_NODES:
      return {
        ...state,
        childNodes: action.childNodes
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

All variable pass in parentNode from actions, parentNode just assign change to state doesn't do anything else.

All logic of `remove node` and `add node` is done by actions, only `UPDATE_CHILD_NODES` in `parentNode`.

### 2. Action just send data to reducer, let reducer to process

actions:

```
export function updateChildNodes(path, nodes) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_CHILD_NODES,
    path: path,
    loading: false,
    loaded: true,
    childNodes: nodes,
  };
}

export function addChild(path, node) {
  return {
    type: ADD_CHILD,
    path: path,
    node: node,
  };
}

export function deleteChild(path, node) {
  return {
    type: DELETE_CHILD,
    path: path,
    node: node,
  };
}

export function deleteNode(node) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // ajax call
    return api.deleteChild(node.path, () => {
      dispatch(deleteChild(node.parent, node))
    })
  }
}

.....
```

parentNode reducer:

```
function parentNode(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DELETE_CHILD:
      let childNodes = state.childNodes.slice() // have to clone obj

      for (var i=0; i <=childNodes.length; i++){
        if (childNodes[i].path == action.node.path){
          childNodes.splice(i, 1)
        }
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        childNodes: childNodes
      };
    case ADD_CHILD:
      let childNodes = state.childNodes.slice() // have to clone obj 
      childNodes.push(node)
      return {
        ...state,
        childNodes: childNodes
      };
    case UPDATE_CHILD_NODES:
      return {
        ...state,
        childNodes: action.childNodes
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

In my option, the solution 2 is more readable and pretty.
But is it good to change the state by mutate an cloned obj? And when I need set `updateTime` by `Date.now()`, I have to generate it from actions and pass to reducer,so that state variables are generated in different place(But I'd like put them together...)

Any opinion for this?

Answer (score 2):

From this redux discussion [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1171):

It is best practice to place most of the logic in the action creators and leave the reducers as simple as possible (closer to your option 1)
for the following reasons:

> Business logic belongs in action-creators. Reducers should be stupid and simple. In many individual cases it does not matter- but consistency is good and so it's best to consistently do this. There are a couple of reasons why:
>
> Action-creators can be asynchronous through the use of middleware like redux-thunk. Since your application will often require asynchronous updates to your store- some "business logic" will end up in your actions.
>
> Action-creators (more accurately the thunks they return) can use shared selectors because they have access to the complete state. Reducers cannot because they only have access to their node.
>
> Using redux-thunk, a single action-creator can dispatch multiple actions- which makes complicated state updates simpler and encourages better code reuse.

Comment: Also see the relevant answer in the Redux FAQ: http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#structure-business-logic

Answer (score 0):

For small apps I usually put my logic in action creators. For more complex situations you may need to consider other options. Here is a summary on pros and cons of different approaches: https://medium.com/@jeffbski/where-do-i-put-my-business-logic-in-a-react-redux-application-9253ef91ce1#.k8zh31ng5

Also, have a look at Redux middleware.

The middleware provides a third-party extension point **between dispatching an action, and the moment it reaches the reducer**.

This is an answer provided by Dan Abramov (author of Redux): [Why do we need middleware for async flow in Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570758/why-do-we-need-middleware-for-async-flow-in-redux)

And here are the official Redux docs: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html