# React Redux - Is there a way to wait until redux dispatch actions are finished via a promise?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I have a route that needs to check if a user has access to the page by checking some data that's being asynchronously populated and is needed to check against the role of the user. Right now, I have a dispatch happening to fetch some data, but is there any way I can wait until that fetch is finished so and access the data?

Here is what my dispatch code looks like:

```
 componentWillMount() {
     this.props.dispatch(fetchWorkOrder(this.props.params.id));
  }
```

And then here is my code for connecting and mapping state to props and all that:

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  workOrder: selectWorkOrderPage(),
  authentication: selectAuthentication(),
  user: selectUser(),
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch,
    fetchWorkOrder,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WorkOrderPage);
```

Is there anything I can do to wait until `this.props.dispatch(fetchWorkOrder(this.props.params.id));` is done loading so I can run some code, such as I would if it were a promise with a `.then()`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sure just use a promise and resolve when the request finishes. you can also use axios which is a promise based library

Comment: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need middleware for async flow in Redux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570758/why-do-we-need-middleware-for-async-flow-in-redux)

Comment: Not *exactly* a duplicate, but answered fully there