# Where to add server request functions in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following Axios request:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.post('http://localhost:3030/api/weather/refresh').then(response => {
      store.dispatch(refreshWeather(response))
    });
  }
```

This sends a dispatch to Redux which is used to feed the presentational container in the common pattern.

My question is - how can I make it do this axios.post() request is re-usable in other components or parts of the app? I have got as far as having it in an external file which is imported, but is there a better way to structure my project so all axios requests are grouped together?

I have the following mapDispatchToProps:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {    
  return {
    onClickRefresh: () => {
      dispatch(refreshWeather(arr))
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to run the same request as the componentDidMount(), but not sure of the best way to make re-usable as explained above.

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout/35415559#35415559 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570758/why-do-we-need-middleware-for-async-flow-in-redux/34599594#34599594 , and http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/ for info on moving async logic out into action creators like thunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by applying the [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware and having an intermediary method perform the request.

```
const REFRESH_WEATHER = 'REFRESH_WEATHER';

export const requestWeather = () => dispatch => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:3030/api/weather/refresh').then(response => {
        dispatch(refreshWeather(response));
    });
};

const refreshWeather = (response) => {
    return {
        type: REFRESH_WEATHER,
        response,
    };
}
```

If you find yourself making a lot of repetitive similar requests you can build out your own api middleware to handle any requests.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern in Redux is to use an Async Action Creator, that way it can be re-used just like any other Action Creator and mapped to your props.

There is a good example in the [official docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#async-action-creators) of how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

config.js

```
module.exports = {
  API_URL: 'http://localhost:3030/api',
};
```

makeRequest.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { API_URL } from './config';

module.exports = (path, method, ...args) => axios[method](API_URL + path, ...args);
```

actions.js

```
module.exports.refreshWeather = (newWeather) => ({
  type: 'REFRESH_WEATHER',
  payload: newWeather,
});
```

stories.js

```
import makeRequest from './makeRequest';
import { refreshWeather as refreshWeatherAction } from './actions';

module.exports.resfreshWeatherStory = (dispatch) => (
    makeRequest('/weather/refresh', 'post')
        .then(response => dispatch(refreshWeatherAction(response)));
);
```

YourComponent.js

```
...
import { refreshWeatherStory } from './stories';
...
componentDidMount() {
    refreshWeatherStory(store.dispatch);
}
...
```

OtherPlace.js

```
...
import { refreshWeatherStory } from './stories';

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onClickRefesh: () => refreshWeatherStory(dispatch),
});
...
```

You get the idea