# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Tags: reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, redux, redux-thunk

I'm currently witting an application using reactjs utilizing react-router, redux, thunk and firebase among other technologies.  Unfortunately I'm getting the following error when I dispatch an actions which is asynchronous.

I went through all the similar questions suggested by stackoverflow and still can't find the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Error:**

> app.js:54628 Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
>       at dispatch (app.js:31576)
>       at Object.fetchBase (app.js:32220)
>       at Object.next (app.js:63640)
>       at app.js:54507
>       at app.js:54622
>       at

**package.json**

```
...
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
"redux": "^3.7.1",
...
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

// Import the root reducer
import allReducers from './reducers';

// import default data
import config from './data/config';

const defaultState = {
  events: [],
  config,
  activeGame: null,
  basePath: '',
};

const router = routerMiddleware(browserHistory);
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(allReducers, defaultState,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk, router)));

export default store;
```

**Actions.js**

```
...
export const fetchBase = () => {
  const organizationRef = database.ref(`users/${auth.currentUser.uid}/organization`);
  return dispatch => {
    organizationRef.once('value', snapshot => {
      dispatch({
        type: ActionTypes.FETCH_BASE,
        payload: snapshot.val()
      });
    });
  };
}; // fetchBase
...
```

Comment: Do not really understand your code(where is action called) but apparently instead of object your action returns function.

Comment: When a user logs into the website, I make a call to `this.props.fetchBase()` to get the users specific base directory in firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for all your help. I did find the issue and am kicking myself.  The code above works fine, the problem is where I registered the store.  I was importing an auxiliary store file which I was using for testing purposes.  Once I updated the real store, I forgot to switch to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think `organizationRef.once` returns firebase.Promise that is why you got that error.

Comment: Redux Thunk should handle any asynchronous requests.

Comment: yeah ,but shouldn't you make `organizationRef.once('value', snapshot => {
      return dispatch({
        type: ActionTypes.FETCH_BASE,
        payload: snapshot.val()
      });
    });`

Comment: The outer function is needed to pass the dispatch function to the firebase Promise.  This part of the code works in another application i've written.  Here is a link to a better and more detailed explanation on how it works.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570758/why-do-we-need-middleware-for-async-flow-in-redux?rq=1)

Comment: Hmm. That's weird indeed. I have found a lib for redux and firebase:
https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/
Maybe that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your action creator looks pretty good, but try to get `ref` to firebase database like this:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/users/${uid}/employees`)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I didn't show this in my posted example, but earlier in my actions.js I initialize my database like this. `const database = firebase.database();`

Answer (score 0):

Your action creator looks fine. The error message indicates, that you're not registering the redux-thunk middleware correctly.

Try to import it as followed:

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
```

and then apply it with

```
const store = createStore(allReducers, defaultState,
   composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk, router)));
```

Got this from: [redux-thunk repo](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#installation)