# What redux-thunk offer for async call?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

I am just getting familiar with `redux` and `redux-thunk`.
I tried the below snippet to work with the `async` call, with `redux` and `redux-thunk`.

```
const redux = require('redux');
const thunk = require('redux-thunk').default;
const axios = require('axios');

const createStore = redux.createStore;
const applyMiddleware = redux.applyMiddleware;
const accessPoint = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/',
    responseType: 'json',
    headers: {
        'Accept-Encoding': '',
    },
});

const FETCH_USER_PENDING = 'FETCH_USER_PENDING';
const FETCH_USER_FULFILLED = 'FETCH_USER_FULFILLED';
const FETCH_USER_REJECTED = 'FETCH_USER_REJECTED';

const initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    users: [],
    error: '',
}

const fetchUserPending = () => {
    return {type: FETCH_USER_PENDING}
}
const fetchUserFulfilled = data => {
    return {type: FETCH_USER_FULFILLED, payload: data}
}
const fetchUserRejected = errorMessage => {
    return {type: FETCH_USER_REJECTED, payload: errorMessage}
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const {type, payload} = action;
    switch(type){
        case FETCH_USER_PENDING: {
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true,
            }
        }
        case FETCH_USER_FULFILLED: {
            return {
                isLoading: false,
                users: payload,
                error: ''
            }
        }
        case FETCH_USER_REJECTED: {
            return {
                isLoading: false,
                users: [],
                error: payload
            }
        }
        default: return state;
    }
}

const fetchUsers = () => {
    return function(dispatch){
        dispatch(fetchUserPending());
        accessPoint.get('users')
            .then(response => {
                dispatch(fetchUserFulfilled(response.data.map(user => user.name)))
            })
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch(fetchUserRejected(error.message));
            })
    }
}

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(store.getState());
})

store.dispatch(fetchUsers());
```

[Code On CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-https-siiko1?file=/src/index.js:0-1717)

This works absolutely fine and gives the expected output.

Also tried the same example without `thunk` and some changes,

```
const redux = require('redux');
const axios = require('axios');

const createStore = redux.createStore;
const accessPoint = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/',
    responseType: 'json',
    headers: {
        'Accept-Encoding': '',
    },
});

const FETCH_USER_PENDING = 'FETCH_USER_PENDING';
const FETCH_USER_FULFILLED = 'FETCH_USER_FULFILLED';
const FETCH_USER_REJECTED = 'FETCH_USER_REJECTED';

const initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    users: [],
    error: '',
}

const fetchUserPending = () => {
    return {type: FETCH_USER_PENDING}
}
const fetchUserFulfilled = data => {
    return {type: FETCH_USER_FULFILLED, payload: data}
}
const fetchUserRejected = errorMessage => {
    return {type: FETCH_USER_REJECTED, payload: errorMessage}
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const {type, payload} = action;
    switch(type){
        case FETCH_USER_PENDING: {
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true,
            }
        }
        case FETCH_USER_FULFILLED: {
            return {
                isLoading: false,
                users: payload,
                error: ''
            }
        }
        case FETCH_USER_REJECTED: {
            return {
                isLoading: false,
                users: [],
                error: payload
            }
        }
        default: return state;
    }
}

const fetchUsers = (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchUserPending());
    accessPoint.get('users')
        .then(response => {
            dispatch(fetchUserFulfilled(response.data.map(user => user.name)))
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(fetchUserRejected(error.message));
        })
}

const store = createStore(reducer);
store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(store.getState());
})

fetchUsers(store.dispatch);
```

[Code On CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-butterfly-5uk6yc?file=/src/index.js)

Here instead of passing function to `store.dispatch()` with a `react-thunk`, I am passing `store.dispatch` to `fetchUsers()` function. And depending on the stages I am dispatching actions to it.

Confusing is what `redux-thunk` offers with the async call when both snippets(one using `redux-thunk` and one without it) produce exact same output (not overall difference but with the above scenario).

If something is wrong with practicing such code, please correct it.

Advance thank you for your input.

Comment: This has been asked before. [Here's one answered by the creator of Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570758/why-do-we-need-middleware-for-async-flow-in-redux), and [another one with some quality answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47031408/why-use-redux-thunk). The TLDR is that you absolutely _can_ use fetch or any other async action with plain Redux, but using Thunk makes it more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Redux middleware system and `redux-thunk` middleware provide a way to express asynchronous actions in a concise manner.

1. You don't need to pass `store.dispatch` and `store.getState` every time when calling the action creator. The Redux [`applyMiddleware`](https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware) API does it for you.
2. You can also [Injecting Config Values Into Thunks](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks#injecting-config-values-into-thunks) using the `withExtraArgument()` API of `redux-thunk`