# Redux, best way to access and use the state inside a middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a situation that I need to send two params in my post requests using axios to all my endpoints. These parameters are already in my store.

So, I create a "middleware" to procede all my requests like so:

```
const POST = async (url, body = {}) => {
  const {Token, UserId} = store.getState().User
  const {DeviceIdentifier} = await GetDeviceInfo()
  const data = {AgentId: UserId, DeviceId: DeviceIdentifier, ...body}
  const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}${url}$`, data, {
    headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${Token}`},
  })

  if (!response.data.Logged) {
    logoutUser()
    return false
  }

  return response
}
```

But, I've been reading a lot of articles saying that using getState() like that is not a good idea...

What should be the best aproch in a situation like that?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Dan Abramov passes a `getState` argument in his Redux Thunk library (`return (dispatch, getState) => {...}`). See [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34599594/327074) to a related question. So it seems like it's reasonable to be able to use `getState` in middleware.

Comment: Is this middleware an action creator

Comment: Sure... Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

When using redux thunk you can supply two arguments `dispatch` and `getState`. To supply more arguments:

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ url, body }))
)

// .withExtraArgument(url) // to supply further one arguments only
```

And then you can use `getState` like:

```
const POST = async (dispatch, getState, {url, body = {}}) => {
  ...
  getState().User
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Using `getState()` in a middleware is totally fine - that's why it's there!

If you'd like to read some extended discussion of some hypothetical concerns and my reasons why it's still okay, my post [Idiomatic Redux: Thoughts on Thunks, Sagas, Abstraction, and Reusability](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/idiomatic-redux-thoughts-on-thunks-sagas-abstraction-and-reusability/) goes into further details.