# Difference between an action creator using redux thunk and a normal async function

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, react-redux, redux-thunk

So I want to understand beyond the basics of Redux thunk and I made two action creators, one of which works and uses redux thunk and other which only uses async but breaks.Below is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

So in both action creators I await for the API request to finish and then return an action ( a JS object with type and payload).

However only the top one works and the bottom one gives an error saying action must be plain object although I return a plain object with 2 properties. I've been really struggling to understand why does the second action creator brakes and would be really nice if someone could explain in details why is it happening.Thank you!

Comment: "although I return a plain object with 2 properties" no you don't. Async function returns a promise that is resolved to whatever you return. So the message is correct, your action creator returns a promise and you don't have a middleware to handle it.

Comment: Please include all the relevant code in the question itself. Images of code are not searchable making the question not useful for future readers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need middleware for async flow in Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570758/why-do-we-need-middleware-for-async-flow-in-redux)

Answer (score 2):

It is because, when you use thunk, you return either an object or function. In 2nd case, when you dispatched your actions something like this `dispatch(fetchUser())`, it didn't return any thing because you are calling an async method. Now code below await will only be executed once async all is done, original call of `dispatch(fetchUser())` is already completed (hint : Only code below await is not executed, but the function call is already over), and `fetchUser()` didn't return any object, but in first case, you are actually returning a function which is calling an async method. This is where the magic of thunk middleware really happens. It executes that function and dispatch an action (hint: you are returning a function which is taking dispatch as an argument) which is executed by thunk. Hope this clears your doubt. I would suggest you to read how async/await really works (hint : event loops/single threaded).

Answer (score 0):

You cant use an async function because it will always returns a promise. Even if you return a value it will be wrapped in a promise and it is returned. If you dont return anything in async function and try to read the value , then undefined will be wrapped in a promise . As redux says action creators should return a plain object which cannot be done directly using async functions.