# How does middleware execute async actions?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am having a little difficulty understanding how Redux-Thunk (or other middleware) execute async actions. From below example, I can see that when `onOrder` is called (maybe via a click event), it will dispatch the action created by `purchaseBurger`. `purchaseBurger` in turn return a function that will dispatch an action indicating purchase started, followed by an http request. My confusion is: When does that function returned by `purchaseBurger` actually gets called and executed? How does it get called too?

```
ContactData.js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
        return {
            onOrder: (orderData) => dispatch(actions.purchaseBurger(orderData))
        }
    }
```

---

```
orders.js
export const purchaseBurgerStart = (orderData) => {
        return {
            type: actionTypes.PURCHASE_BURGER_START
       }
    }

export const purchaseBurger = (orderData) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(purchaseBurgerStart());
        axios.post('/orders.json', orderData)
        .then(response => {

        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({ loading: false });
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: visit the @dan answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34599594/6818430

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the source of [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js) you will see that when you dispatch an action it checks to see if the action is a function, and if it is it will invoke the function passing in `dispatch, getState, extraArgument` as arguments.

So when you call `dispatch(purchaseBurger())` it will dispatch the returned function from `purchaseBurger` as an action, the middleware will then check the type and see that it is a function and will call it with `dispatch` as the first argument