# In React / Redux, is it just fine to make a generic dispatch as props to dispatch any action at all?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In one of [Dan Abramov's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34599594/325419), there is code

```
// action creator
function loadData(dispatch, userId) { // needs to dispatch, so it is first argument
  return fetch(`http://data.com/${userId}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      data => dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS', data }),
      err => dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_DATA_FAILURE', err })
    );
}

// component
componentWillMount() {
  loadData(this.props.dispatch, this.props.userId); // don't forget to pass dispatch
}
```

It seems the `mapDispatchToProps` just maps a generic dispatch as props (as `this.props.dispatch`), so this component can dispatch *any action* at all?

First, is it a good form, or is it just an example but we should make it specific dispatch, such as `this.props.dataReceived`?

Second, so it looks like for the above code, the `mapDispatchToProps` would be written as:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatchOfReduxStore => {
  return {
    dispatch: dispatchOfReduxStore
  }
}
```

or even just:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    dispatch
  }
}
```

and simplified to:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ dispatch })
```

and `this.props.dispatch` becomes a versatile dispatch?

I also found that when we simply omit the `mapDispatchToProps` in `connect()`, then `this.props.dispatch` is automatically available.

Comment: He is not talking about mapping `dispatch` he's talking about mapping action creators

Comment: @sylvanaar I am saying why is there a `props.dispatch`? never seen that before

Comment: It is the default behavior of `connect` to inject `dispatch` if you don't supply `mapDispatchToProps`. If you do supply it - you have to inject it yourself - as you have discovered.

Comment: I see... "Your component will receive dispatch by default, i.e., when you do not supply a second parameter to connect()"  https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapdispatchtoprops-object-dispatch-ownprops-object  https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#default-dispatch-as-a-prop

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason for binding `dispatch` to your actions with `mapDispatchToProps` is to hide redux from your connected component.

Without binding `dispatch`, your component must know what your actions are and remember that they do nothing without calling them as a parameter to `dispatch`.

With binding, your component just knows that it has these functions in `props` that it can simply call when needed.

The other benefit would be arguably cleaner code, since you can just call `this.props.myAction()` instead of `this.props.dispatch(myAction())`.

I don't think its a hard right or wrong. I think some of it is preference. I prefer to write my components to where they only know about the props given to them. But you may prefer to make it explicit that your component is using redux to dispatch actions.