# When to use dispatch in an action creator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, es6-promise, redux-thunk

I have defined two functions in my ActionCreator.js file
First:

```
export const getAudioForVerification = ()=>{
return fetch(baseUrl+'audio',{
    // Get Request
}
.then(response=>response.json());}
```

Second:

```
export const audioVerificationResult = (audioId,verificationResult) =>(dispatch)=>{
return fetch(baseUrl+'audio',{
    // PUT Request
})
.then(response=>response.json());
}
```

MainFunction:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
getAudioForVerification: ()=>dispatch(getAudioForVerification),
audioVerificationResult: (audioId,verificationResult)=>dispatch(audioVerificationResult(audioId,verificationResult))
});
```

Q1: If I remove dispatch from my Second function: audioVerificationResult I get an error

> Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Why doesn't such an error appear for the first function as well?

Q2: The first function returns a promise (I can use .then in my MainComponent after I call this function) while the second one doesnot. Why?

I have started learning about Promises, Redux and Thunk (Web dev in general) quite recently. If the questions are too broad please direct me to a learning source.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions in your `ActionCreator.js` are not exactly **action creators** since they are not returning `plain object` like the [redux docs](https://read.reduxbook.com/markdown/part1/04-action-creators.html) suggests. They are just js functions.

You don't need to `dispatch` if you are using `.then()` in your component and reading the `results/data`. `dispatch` only helps you with the `redux store` updates.

Hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570758/why-do-we-need-middleware-for-async-flow-in-redux/34599594#34599594) helps you to understand granular details about middleware better.

Comment: Then I should remove these function from mapDispatchToProps and rather than defining them in my ActionCreator, I should define them in my MainComponent. Is this the best way to go about it or is there a better approach? I wanted all my fetch in a single file therefore decided to define these in my ActionCreator.js file even though they were not accessing the store.

Comment: Ideally no point of keeping them in`mapDispatchToProps` and accessing it via `props`. You can remove `mapDispatchToProps` argument of `connect` altogether. It is still better to keep them in `ActionCreator.js` (separate file) for SoC and maintainability. May be you can change the file name.