# What is Redux Thunk for?

Tags: redux

I can't understand advantage of Redux Thunk in async requests.

```
....

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch:any)=>{
    return{
        onStoreData: (val:number)=> push(dispatch, val),
    };
};
```

```
export const push = (dispatch:any, val: number) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        dispatch(
            {
                type: Actions.PUSH,
                val: val
            }
        );
    }, 2000);
};
```

This code works without Redux Thunk even when there are many requests in the same moment. Is this code safe? What is point of Redux Thunk?

Comment: Answered in https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411423/6281832

Comment: So above code is fine, and Redux Thunk is just for cosmetic purposes and shorter code?

Comment: Your code works, but gets more complicated over time. Another good thing that redux-thunk provides access to the whole state via getState. Another question that explains the difference https://stackoverflow.com/q/34570758/6281832

Also, check the source code of redux-thunk, it's really tiny https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js