# Unable to understand double arrow function which returns another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I have been doing a React course and I am unable to understand double arrow functions correctly. Could someone please explain me this piece of code

```
export const fetchDishes = () => (dispatch) => {
   dispatch(dishesLoading(true));
   setTimeout(() => {
     dispatch(addDishes(DISHES));
   }, 2000);
}
```

All I understood till now is that fetchDishes is a function which takes no arguments but returns another function named dispatch and the dispatch function calls itself(dispatches an action).

I am looking for a detailed explaination, bonus if you could explain a bit in terms of react too

Comment: It's a function that returns a function that takes `dispatch` as an argument, likely as part of a redux-thunk action creator (i.e. async actions). https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions

Answer (score 1):

> All I understood till now is that fetchDishes is a function which
> takes no arguments but returns another function

Till this point you are right but later it does not return function named **dispatch** but instead take argument named **dispatch** which is an callback (or in Reactjs dispatcher or smth else) and this callback is called with those 2 values at very beginning and after 2 seconds.

```js
    const DISHES = [1, 2, 3];
    const dishesLoading = (someBool) => someBool;
    const addDishes = (dishes) => dishes.length;

    const fetchDishes = () => (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(dishesLoading(true));
        setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(addDishes(DISHES));
        }, 2000);
    };

    const fetchDishesDispatcher = fetchDishes();

    fetchDishesDispatcher(function someCallbackFunction(value) {
        // first outputed value will be result of "dishesLoading(true)" function
        // after 2 seconds second value will be outputed with result of "addDishes(DISHES)" function
        console.log(value);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of using a **middleware** in redux such as redux-thunk or redux-saga. It provides a third-party extension point between dispatching an action, and the moment it reaches the reducer, which means it adds a protection layer between action and reducer which can be used to call asynchronous API and check for errors before hand, routing, crash reporting etc.

You can read more about it [here](https://hackernoon.com/how-redux-middlewares-can-be-helpful-for-you-55dfe152b5e) and a thread on [stackoverflow too.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34584313/10337435)

Answer (score 0):

Using classic JS functions, the code could be rewritten like this:

```
export const fetchDishes = function() {
   return function(dispatch) {
       dispatch(dishesLoading(true));
       setTimeout(() => {
           dispatch(addDishes(DISHES));
       }, 2000);
   }
}
```

So the function `fetchDishes` returns function, whose argument is `dispatch` of type function.

To be honest, I don't understand how this kind of nesting is helpful if the first function doesn't have any arguments (one could just export the function returned by `fetchDishes`). To see what is the purpose of double arrow functions, read [What do multiple arrow functions mean in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782922/what-do-multiple-arrow-functions-mean-in-javascript) .